# What is wrong with this question about asking for the proper HTML tag for a given type of content?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, opinion-based

Here's my post, word for word (deleted by various mods for being "opinion based")

> ## HTML Purists: what's the most correct tag for a slogan on a business website? [closed]
>
> What's the most semantically correct markup to use for a slogan on a business website? For instance, I'd use `<slogan>`, if it existed:
>
> ```
> <title>Stack Overflow</title>
> <slogan>Best website since 1992!</slogan>
> ```

Score: -6. Reason: Primarily opinion based.

What the heck is wrong with this post? How is this opinion based?!?! If I asked: What is the most correct tag for a paragraph? Is this opinion based?

If I asked what is the most correct tag for a list item? Is this opinion based?

How is this opinion based? The whole point of HTML5 is that it is semantic.

Comment: If you look at the Google results when searching for HTML5 slogan tag you will see hundreds of posts containing different answers - each an opinion. As an aside - are you just looking to argue because of your recent downvotes?

Comment: @JayBlanchard that's because there's no designated tag for a slogan, so everyone has their own workaround. So do I deserve 6 downvotes and a question ban as a result for asking a legitimate question?

Comment: It isn't a legit question (*for SO*), it is asking for opinion.

Comment: +1, Why are people downvoting this question? He's coming to meta asking for criticism and help with using the site and gets downvotes? This seems silly IMO, this (the meta post) is a legit question.

Comment: They're DV'ing here because they don't agree with the OP. That's pretty standard behavior on MSO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard how can you disagree with a question? "What is wrong with this question" "I disagree"

Comment: I'm not downvoting for disagreeing. If this was just asking for guidance, I would upvote. However this is more a rant than a question.

Comment: @Renan no it's more of a question than a rant.

Comment: People do it all the time here @NickManning and there are lots of posts concerning this behavior. These fake Internet points don't count against your other fake Internet points, so it should be less of a deal.

Comment: @NickManning Compare "Why is this post opinion-based?" vs "How is this opinion based?!?!" Both are questions but the 2nd implies that the question whose opinion-based nature is brought up for discussion is, *in fact*, not opinion-based. People can disagree *with this implication*. Also, compare "What is wrong with this post?" vs "What *the heck* is wrong with this post?" [Emphasis added.] The latter implies that there is nothing wrong with it. Again, an opportunity for disagreement.

Comment: Okay sorry I implied that my original post was good.

Comment: +1: nothing is wrong with your question.  -1: your question is opinion based, probably not definitively answered, and needs to be fixed (if you can).

Comment: The way you've written this post, it reads like you're yelling in frustration. While frustration may indeed be your current mental state, peope usually stay away from someone who's doing that. You should try to express your problem calmly and in a way that shows you've considered the problem at hand -- which includes doing some research on Meta about your problem. (You might also want to look on [Meta.SE] for information.)

Comment: Seems you deleted the question you were really getting flamed on so I wanted give you a heads up....

Comment: @JayBlanchard the one I asked today? No I didnt

Comment: ....Hence my first comment in that post @NickManning. Your question, in a word, *sucks*. The code doesn't have any flexbox included with it, heck your code isn't even in your post at all - just a link to an incomplete fiddle. My apologies for such strong language but I figure that it is the only way to get your very limited attention. It is no wonder that you have suffered a question ban, which is surprising to me because you seemingly have supplied some brilliant answers. If you're planning on asking more questions you may want to brush up on making them complete. And quit trying end arounds.

Comment: Then someone saved you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard my question did not suck. Okay, I forgot to include the code other than the jFiddle but why didn't someone just nicely point that out? I would have edited it.

Comment: No one pointed it out because you tried to do an end around because of your question ban.

Comment: @JayBlanchard True

Comment: Furthermore you didn't include flexbox *even in your fiddle*.

Comment: Yes I did...see the CSS `main{display:flex}`. I wish they hadn't deleted the question. I would take your suggestions and resubmit to meta until someone copy pastes it for me.

Comment: No one will do that, Meta is not the place for those kinds of questions. That is the end around that will get you banned from both sites if you're not careful.

Comment: Maybe someone will do it...

Comment: Not given your recent rep on Meta. And if you ask the question will get eliminated again. You'll not find anyone to copy and paste your question, especially if it isn't well written, because their rep would suffer.

Comment: All right all right I get it

Comment: The way to fix the ban is to improve your questions and seek to have them reopened via Meta. Make sure that you're spot on with your question edits (including code, clearly describing the problem, clearly describing the desired outcome, etc.) I'll be on the lookout and will cast reopen votes where proper and offer suggestions on improvements where I need to. Gimme a link to your fiddle @NickManning

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you...I will do my best

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's start with the text of the close reason:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

So your question isn't necessarily a bad one. I personally think the question itself is OK. However, I'd argue that it's not possible to determine a single correct element here, at most we could come up with a list of tags that come close in semantic meaning. Thus, primarily opinion based.

Now, the downvotes:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Your question is clear and it is useful. But you have not shown any research effort along the lines of *"I think `<foo>` or `<bar>` are good candidates because of this and that"* or *"I read that [...]"*.

Comment: It was deleted but I had answered my own question saying I had decided on the `p` tag since a slogan is kind of a paragraph in a way. But everyone was just hating on me at the time.

Answer (score 13):

A little bit of common sense is in order.

A paragraph is a paragraph, a section is a section, a header is a header. These are simple buildig blocks that we use for creating pages.

A slogan is not a simple building block. There are more ways to make them than you have bones in your body.

On top of that, what is best for you now may not be best for you tomorrow, and will surely not be best for anyone else. Because of this, this kind of question is not considered useful here.

You could make the question more useful if you described your problem **in detail**. If you have a case that is common and for which resolution patterns exist, you'll have more chances of getting help.

Please read the relevant help section: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Emphasis on:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>   * every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Because that's exactly what your question looks like to me, as per your description.

Comment: I thought there might be a tag that is well known to be symantically correct...it's not always so black and white as the name of the tag equals what it is. For example, article tags are for anything syndicated. So there's no <blog-post> tag but article is the correct answer if I asked for what's the correct tag for syndicated blog posts. My question was as detailed as it needed to be. I wanted to use a different tag other than div for my slogan to make my HTML semantically correct.

Comment: What you said there about blog posts is an opinion. I might want my blog posts non-syndicated, and I will surely have more stuff in the article tag otherwise.

Comment: technically everything is an opinion. We can get philosophical if we want. Do we even exist? This is a site for programmers to offer help to each other---but the community is ridiculously cranky.

Comment: Technically not *everything* is an opinion. Over generalization will get you everywhere.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know...my point was that he overgeneralized me

Answer (score 7):

StackOverflow is for programming related questions that have a definite answer. If there cannot be a textbook answer but just opinions, then the question no longer qualifies.

For example, if you asked what a semantic tab was or if you could use a semantic tag, than the question would qualify. Instead you asked what would be a 'good' tag to use and that is entirely dependent on the individuals' preferences.