# Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?

Tags: discussion, voting, meta

I'd like to start with saying that I emailed @Shog9 back in August with the text below, because I'm not a particularly good writer, and I was hoping he'd be able to write up a nice post here. A couple weeks ago I learned that he's quite a busy person, so I'm posting myself now. That being said...

The last few weeks/months I've become increasingly concerned about the voting culture on MSO.

There are many legitimate support questions that get downvoted. If anything, it's a good thing that people find their way to Meta and ask for help on something they do not understand. I feel sad when these questions get downvoted, and you can often see the OP comment to ask why the downvotes are happening. Of course there are crap questions posted under the support tag too, that shows the OP did not even try one bit to see if a similar question exists.

To a lesser extent I see the same happening in the discussion tag. Downvotes are often justified as "I disagree with your discussion", and while that's often a fair downvote, I feel that there are also quite a bit of discussions that should be voted on based on how interesting they are. Again, people taking the time to come to Meta and discuss something before they do a certain action on the main site, and the discussion gets downvoted. Instead a disagreeing answer should be posted and voted on, in my opinion.

What do you all think of this? Is there an actual problem? If so, how can we try to "fix" it?

Comment: do you have any specific posts in mind?

Comment: @SamIam I kind of expected that question. I don't have specific examples with me right now, but any somewhat regular visitor of MSO has probably noticed this. I'll try to compile a list of examples later this evening.

Comment: I'm not sure that can be "fixed", actually. Meta is murder, after all, and downvotes on discussions can be useful to get the community's general opinion at a glance. There is also no impact on reputation, so...

Comment: I have seen this as well.  If I get some time, I will try to find some examples.  And it usually isn't the questions that get 4 and 5 downvotes, it is the questions that get 1 or 2 downvotes just because someone presumably "disagreed" with a question that nothing to agree/disagree with.  Those are the ones that annoy me most because it drives away someone for just being interested in understanding an aspect of the site.

Comment: Maybe http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271842/is-it-okay-to-just-ask-for-an-algorithm-to-a-problem would be such a post if Tim hadn't posted his comment.

Comment: [You're not the only one concerned about this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring/268788#268788)

Comment: I don't find this to be a useful starting point for a discussion without a definition/examples of your subject: "legitimate support questions" that are downvoted. Given that one valid reason to downvote may be the legitimacy of the post, your entire concern hangs on what a "legitimate support question" is. It's likely that not everyone has the same definition  as you; answerers therefore will dispute or agree with what they _think_ you mean. That's not a particularly productive way to have a rational argument.

Comment: This could be an example http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272602/what-is-wrong-with-this-question-about-asking-for-the-proper-html-tag-for-a-give

Comment: Pretend that's an SO question, @eddie_cat: "Here's my code, word for word (throwing a "Diphthong Exception")

`code`


Diphthong Reason: too many diphthongs in your code

What the heck is wrong with this code? How is this causing an exception?!?! If I wrote: `other code`? Is this too many diphthongs?

If I wrote `other code`? Is this too many diphthongs?

How is this too many diphthongs? The whole point of XXX is that it is diphthongian." (Granted this is not exact.) Is this a good question? Is it well-written? Does it show research? Is it useful to the future?

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's not the best example, but it was the first I found. Imagine if the tone of that post was more reasonable and OP was simply asking how to improve/follow the guidelines of the community. I have seen questions like that appear here and get downvoted.

Comment: But the tone of _that_ post isn't reasonable, @eddie_cat. This is what I was saying in my earlier comment to Stijn: I can imagine that, but when _I_ imagine a reasonably-toned post asking politely how to fix a question, it's _not_ negatively-scored. That's what _I_ remember. You remember something else. Without examples to anchor the discussion, we're talking about made-up stuff inside our own heads.

Comment: Providing proper support is a *job*.  The likes of General Electrics operate a call center where a friendly voice doesn't mind explaining *again* how to cook an egg in the microwave.  If support is a core business requirement then don't leave it up to unpaid volunteers to get that job done.  So SE doesn't think it is, little reason for us to assume it should be more important to us when it is not to them.

Comment: Might be off-topic since you're talking about voting culture on MSO, but I'm concerned of [this post on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240357/fonts-on-stackexchange-websites-looking-ugly-after-installing-helvectica-on-pc). I'm not sure why it was downvoted; was it because of the wording/tone? No effort? Unclear? At the time I commented, it had score of -3. And I still think that might be a legit issue.

Comment: [Here's an example from yesterday](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272602/what-is-wrong-with-this-question-about-asking-for-the-proper-html-tag-for-a-give#comment100263_272602). Bothers me too.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum actually your comment was what made me finally post this here :)

Comment: in short, the answer appears to be, "no. we can't. now get off my lawn."

Comment: I'm under the impression that voting on meta is to indicate agreement or disagreement with what is said. So what is broken about that?

Comment: @HansPassant, we *have* support!  Sounds like we're doing a lousy job letting people know [where it is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) (in the footer of every page) and that support questions are welcome there. We don't *actively* push these types of questions there for 2 reasons: 1) Many of them are "can I", "should I", "is it okay", and those benefit greatly from broader community feedback.2) "Contact Us" generates no public artifact, so the information isn't potentially re-usable by others.  Just to be clear, support questions can always be submitted through the "Contact Us" link.

Comment: It's not just on MSO, I've noticed the same on SO (along with increased incivility).

Comment: Incivility is an Escher staircase, @Paul; people have been complaining about "increasing" rudeness [since the week the site came out of beta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/9953/1).

Comment: @JoshCaswell: They waited that long? Unbelievable.

Comment: @Jaydles `Many of them are "can I", "should I", "is it okay", and those benefit greatly from broader community feedback.` - I would assume that you agree that down votes are part of this broader community feedback? A person asking "can I crosspost this on both SO and DBA" would get a down vote rather than a dozen `no. Additional text here` and similar comments. Additionally, official SE responses to support inquiries on MSO seem to have a placating effect on the voters (though may be subject to votes of their own if they seem to run counter to the community's ideas). Prompt responses may help.

Comment: @MichaelT, good point on prompt responses.  As to down voting working as an answer, I think it's unclear to the poster what's meant by them: You can't know if downvotes mean, "you're ranting; posts like this aren't encouraged" or "thanks for checking here, but no, you oughtn't do that". Plus, most "no"s want for "... Because you'd be creating two sets of answers," or some other explanation.

Comment: @MichaelT A better option would be one such comment, upvoted 12 times. Better yet, an answer "no, crossposting is discouraged on SE", upvoted 12 times.

Comment: Well one way to fix that, if it becomes a big issue is to compulsary add a comment when you down-vote, and give a short description as to why you down-voted. that would discourage the hobos out-here to just simply press the down-vote button. At least then a peer can delete the crap down-vote comments and get the vote back up. Isn't that what teachers do at school and colleges and universities when they mark wrong questions? they leave remarks don't they.

Comment: @TylerH I just posted a short answer here about that

Comment: another example http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272908/why-was-one-of-my-comments-deleted

Comment: I can't help feeling it's more than a little sad that people downvote without comment when something is clearly tagged as a discussion topic.

Comment: As a general idea: You want to keep meta clean from rubbish on the one hand but you want to keep as many as possible even from the half-good ideas around because if you set the bar too high, you might lose precious content and in general create a climate of fear! So it's important to have a balanced approach. A careful audition of recent deletions should tell you if adjustments are needed.

Comment: @eddit_cat how is http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272908/why-was-one-of-my-comments-deleted an example of this? It has +6 upvotes and -2 downvotes.

Comment: This could be an example - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377197/are-questions-about-specific-questions-off-topic-on-meta-stack-overflow

Comment: I'm done on meta after one answer got many downvotes. The sentence "I don't agree with you" is not an argument if many things in the post are written and without leaving a comment. So downvoters: you want the power? proceed! You want dialogue? then feel free to upvote whatever you like, but be more respectful and avoid many downvotes.

Comment: @David I think you have misunderstood the way it works on meta. If you post something here, especially on a discussion that is meant to set policy, the voting is exactly for agreement or disagreement. Nothing more. There's nothing personal about it. It's not disrespectful to not agree with you. If you posted something that lots of users disagree with, you know it from the score. Your view will likely *not* become policy though :) Unless you post something that doesn't answer the Question, then the votes reflect that.

Comment: might be that I misunderstood it. But I can't change it how I feel about it and I don't see a reason to spend time on something that is honored with downvotes primary. Sure there are some people like you answering respectful, but I've not the feeling that all are behaving respectful. I don't need that and if more positive feedback would come - or at least not so negative, then more people would engage here probably too.

Answer (score 224):

So I've been kinda chewing on this since your email, because... It's one of those simple questions that defies a simple answer. You're not the only person to raise this concern, of course: several respected users, moderators and even co-workers have expressed dismay upon seeing reasonable questions here that attract a pile of downvotes.

But as tempting as it is to join in the hand-wringing - and as convenient as it would be to just blow it off as the usual whining... There's a subtlety here that I think gets overlooked, and I'm still not sure of the best way to address it.

That said, here are my current thoughts on the matter:

### The challenges of persuading a large, critical audience

Every week here at Stack Exchange, there are two meetings held concerning the development of the engine that powers these sites: one composed of the team of developers that actually *implement* changes, the other composed of [the Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do). For those of you not familiar with the latter and too lazy to follow that link, we're basically this guy:

[image]

Everyone involved on both teams has *very* strong opinions about how these sites should operate. So when a new feature is proposed - even very trivial changes to how some bit of the system works - it is *extremely likely* that the need for the change will be challenged.

Most of us have at one point or another found these meetings to be... Draining. No matter how polite the actual conversation might be, you're effectively standing up before a group of people you trust and respect while they tell you that your idea is confusing, unnecessary, and possibly detrimental to the future of the system and the company. And your job is to explain, calmly and persuasively, the details of how it would work, and why it is both necessary and beneficial. Before everyone just gets sick of talking about it and moves on.

Why is this relevant? Because these discussions are essentially *meta in miniature*, the lifecycle of a post here compressed into a few minutes. The same topics, the same concerns, and - if you don't come prepared - the same harsh reception. And the rules for success are the same as well:

1. **Have a problem, state it clearly.** If you can't communicate the problem you're trying to solve, folks will just guess at it - or worse, assume there isn't one and you're just proposing *change for the sake of change*. Either of those options are bad, but the latter is particularly likely to torpedo any chance of a good reception right off the bat.
2. **Citation needed.** So you think there's a problem... Got any *proof?* Again, you need to put to rest the tendency for folks to think you're just making something up, or blowing a tiny problem out of proportion to justify a change. Links to past discussions, to posts where the problem has occurred, to queries that illustrate the pervasiveness of the problem... All of these are helpful in convincing your audience that the problem you're solving is both *real* and *serious in nature.*
3. **The brilliant solution, in brief.** Ok, now you're ready to present the solution you're hoping to see implemented. Can you summarize it? If so, you probably already put that summary in the title or introduction - but now that folks understand the problem, you should repeat it so they can start thinking about how it might actually help to address the problem. If you can't communicate the essential nature of what you're proposing in a simple sentence, you might need to put some more thought into it... If folks can't quickly grasp the essence of what you're suggesting, they're quite likely to start thinking about their own solutions to the problem instead.
4. **Show your work.** How did you arrive at *this* solution? What led you down this path? You don't have to tell your life's story here, but at least hinting at your thought process is a good way to get your audience into a mindset able to understand your proposed solution. This is particularly helpful for *radical* changes, which might otherwise be rejected outright.
5. **The brilliant solution, in detail.** If you've gotten this far, you're doing *really* well. You have their attention, their sympathy, some amount of understanding... Now you just need to show that you've thought through all of the edge cases where your solution might fall apart. Is it open to abuse? Can it scale, up *and* down? Is it gonna break if no one uses it? Is it gonna break if *everyone* uses it? What other systems does it interact with - will it affect them? How? How will we monitor this to make sure it's working?  This is your last chance to fail - if answering these questions takes too much time, there's a good chance the change will be seen as overly-complex unless the potential payoff is *staggeringly huge*.

If this sounds like a lot of work, well... It is. Although I'll wager it's not *unfamiliar* to many if not most of you.

### Why folks fall on their faces here on Meta

Simply put, many people do not do *any* of the necessary steps I outlined above. And I'm not just talking about the folks posting under [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) - many support requests and even discussions create an implicit expectation for the existence of a problem to be solved, of the existence of a well-considered solution. Want a question re-opened? Closed? Upvoted? Downvoted? Commented on? Well... Why? Where did things go wrong? What led to that? Did you put any thought into this at all, or are you treating this site like [an agony aunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_column) where you describe your woes and hope someone will do your thinking for you?

Of course, it's usually the latter. And sometimes, we *do* offer a solution - because we're nice like that. But not always, and not without some irritation...

Because by posting here, you're stepping up on a very large soapbox, in the middle of a very large crowd of very busy people... And as nice as we might all be as individuals, you're taking time away from something else we were planning on doing. We'd like to know you're not wasting it.

### The value of downvotes, at last

So what does this have to do with downvotes? Well, voting is how *groups* express their collective opinions. It's pointless to say that a given post *should* be scored higher; you're just expressing your individual opinion, which that score was never intended to reflect. If you think it's a good post and you've upvoted, then you've had your say - *move on*. The same goes for downvotes, of course - if you think a post is overrated then make sure you downvote and then quiet down - you've had your say, *score-wise*.

One of my biggest frustrations in [the system that preceded Meta](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/) was the *inability* to express disagreement by voting. Without the option to downvote, folks were implicitly encouraged to post criticisms in the comments - with the result being frequent, long, and not particularly constructive arguments on every controversial idea. Don't get me wrong - laying out your objections is a good idea - but if 20 people have the same objection, they really shouldn't need to be stated 20 times to "count". Especially if "tact" isn't exactly your thing, or you prefer ad hominem arguments.

Voting on meta - which wasn't so much a design decision as it is something we got free with the system re-purposed from the main site - turns out to be a much *gentler* way of expressing dissatisfaction with a post, particularly in cases where it has already been answered. And of course, like the main sites, there's a well-accepted tradition of downvoting *questions* that show either a lack of research or are simply hopelessly unclear - again, offering an alternative to blunt criticisms in comments.

This - fast, efficient feedback - is the value of downvotes to the *site*, to *other readers*, to the *voter*... But there's a certain advantage to the author as well: **they force introspection.** Voting is anonymous; you don't know *who* up- or down-voted your post, and the results appear in aggregate. You cannot blame an individual; you must either blame *everyone*, or... yourself.

And indeed, the common tendency *is* for folks whose posts are downvoted to blame *everyone*. "Meta sucks", they say - and returning only when absolutely necessary, tend to find this initial impression reinforced. This is not unique to meta - [a recent study](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/jure/pubs/disqus-icwsm14.pdf) suggests that downvoting in forums *hurts* the quality of future posts by the same author, potentially encouraging deviant behavior instead of constructive improvements... An effect familiar to most people who've used traditional forums.

But that's not the *only* option. For those of us who come here seeking genuine feedback, votes are invaluable, a way to quickly gauge the community's perception of our ideas, attitudes and presentation styles that simply isn't available otherwise. More than a few times, a downvote has reminded me to revisit a post written in haste, adding clarifications or revising my opinions after re-reading it with a more critical eye. This is *not* the primary purpose of voting - but for those willing to use it, they can become a valuable tool for self-improvement.

### Yes, yes, many words... So is meta broken or not, and if so can we fix it?

It's not broken; it's working exactly as intended, as upsetting as that might be at times. But we might still be able to fix it...

For starters, let's start by looking at the tools already at-hand:

- There was [a FAQ sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240186/faq-sidebar-for-per-site-metas) on the *old* Meta SO, in recognition of both [the Community FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/faq) and how frequently some questions were re-asked. I've re-enabled that here, in hope of catching a few more people before they ask common duplicates.

Going forward, there are a few additional things I think might be worth doing.

- It's possible to customize the guidance shown on /questions/ask and the interstitial page shown to new meta users; let's think about what we can to do help folks get a bit more guidance on how to best ask questions here.
- There are a lot of folks here who are probably a bit more *protective* of Meta than is strictly necessary - although it shares the same membership as Stack Overflow, privileges here are slightly different and more importantly the number of *active* users is much smaller; we can afford to relax a *little bit*. I'll give some thought to writing up some guidance there too. **Update:** separate discussion here: [What is a meta for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/what-is-a-meta-for)

#### Related: [A Proposal for More Constructive Downvoting on Meta: Express Disagreement by Answering the Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans/194090#194090)

Comment: The top half of this answer should probably be in a meta how-to-ask that is shoved in front of all users asking their first meta question, much like the SO how to ask is put in front of first time SO questions.

Comment: The top half of this answer should be put into (perhaps separate sections for the question/answer pieces) of the *main* how to ask. That was... an amazing explanation of how to construct a post. Perhaps a few of the "change request" specifics could be removed, but the general construction was **awesome**.

Comment: "by posting here, you're stepping up on a very large soapbox, in the middle of a very large crowd of very busy people... And as nice as we might all be as individuals, you're taking time away from something else we were planning on doing. We'd like to know you're not wasting it." I really liked this point.

Comment: By some of the logic presented here, we should be able to downvote on comments, too.

Comment: I often wonder how things would have turned out if UserVoice had the concept of negative reputation (or down-voting). Probably not a huge impact, but you kinda have to wonder who wouldn't be here today.

Comment: Even simple bugreports get downvoted at times. I will never understand that culture that is going on here. Related reading: [Why Stack Overflow’s Voting System Is Truly Harmful](http://expertflow.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/why-stack-oveflows-voting-system-is-truly-harmful/) Alas, I do not agree with this answer. It certainly is broken.

Comment: That's a good film by the way :)

Comment: @TimPost, Shog, Do you think it would help to edit the downvote tooltip on posts that have already reached a negative score of something like -10, warning users that additional downvotes at this point are not very helpful and will likely result in negative behavior from the poster? I know many people won't read it, however I know others will, and it would be one way of getting the message out there to the community in general about the official SE position on excessive downvotes.

Comment: I think that would be treating a symptom, @Rachel - if a post hits -10, there's a bigger problem underlying that. We *could* have a pop-up that explains how to help beleaguered askers though - more discussion on that in the answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240440/what-is-a-meta-for

Comment: `It's not broken...[b]ut we might still be able to fix it` - but if it ain't broke why are you suggesting it needs fixin'? `There are a lot of folks here who are probably a bit more protective of Meta than is strictly necessary` - well that's the understatement of the year. The truth is the geeks will eventually be here alone playing "What tag can we burninate next?"

Comment: This should be automatically linked whenever a meta question reaches 5 downvotes.

Comment: No one's ever gonna read all this, @enderland. I guarantee you, most of the votes here are for the picture at the top.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm an optimist, what can I say..

Comment: I tried, got stuck 75% of the way through. Very very nice post from what I read. It almost doesn't belong here, as this is a life skill.

Comment: @Shog9 Is it possible to do one more +1 for **...And your job is to explain, calmly and persuasively...**

Comment: "I've re-enabled that here" I'm definitely not seeing the side bar as in MSE, intended/broken?

Comment: @Servy [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377201/1569204) is my list of things I wish I knew before I posted on meta.

Comment: That is (the picture) Tom "jump to conclusions" Smykowski from [Office Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space), from [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDEL4Ty950Q) (00 min 11 secs).

Answer (score 27):

Tossing together a search of negatively scored questions tagged support in recent time: [[support] is:question score:-20..-1 created:2014-07..2014-10](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+is%3Aquestion+score%3A-20..-1+created%3A2014-07..2014-10) there are indeed a number of them.

Many of them are lack of research questions "What does OP stand for?" and there are ***many*** of the "why am I post banned" that apparently didn't read the message.

In my cursory glance, there are some support questions that are mistagged (and even on the wrong site).  There's one about "close votes" asking if its close or close as a translation question (better suited for [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour)?), retag requests that people disagree with.

The more outstandingly negative ones are things like feature requests for search for skill level that was tagged with support, a question about a post getting deleted and a NSFW domain name, asking where to ask about naming a C++ class (asking if it is for the Stack Exchange sites [P.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)), unable to bounty a question because its on hold, why was a given answer (plagiarized) deleted?

All in all, of the rather significantly negatively-voted questions, many of them are questions that would either be found with a search, someone complaining about something, asking why a particular post was closed/deleted, or mistagged feature/discussions.

---

Let's look at some examples brought up in comments and look into why people might have reacted with downvotes to them:

- [Deleted answer, don't understand why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272333/deleted-answer-dont-understand-why)

  In this case, a person was asking about why their answer was deleted. The majority of the answers in recent times were publicizing a particular [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) repository that the OP was a contributor to. The community tends to take a rather harsh view of spam, and people asking about why their posts that were interpreted as spam also get this treatment.
- [Question on-hold as "off topic", asking for research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272073/question-on-hold-as-off-topic-asking-for-research)

  Recommendation questions also suffer from this guilt by association. Such questions appear to have skipped over the tour and help center and asked a question that was a library shopping question. If the OP had read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it would clearly have been understood before hand. Such downvotes are as old as the Internet (though not always with votes) for people not reading the FAQ in a community before posting.
- [Can I crosspost to stackoverflow a question that was barely seen on DBA?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271906/can-i-crosspost-to-stackoverflow-a-question-that-was-barely-seen-on-dba)

  Likely, the downvotes were answering the question in the title. Can you? No. The community is expressing its disagreement with the premise that reposting something that was not seen on some other Stack Exchange site is acceptable.
- [What is wrong with this question about asking for the proper HTML tag for a given type of content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272602/what-is-wrong-with-this-question-about-asking-for-the-proper-html-tag-for-a-give)

  This post reads more like a rant about closing than a question of how to improve:

  > What the heck is wrong with this post? How is this opinion based?!?! If I asked: What is the most correct tag for a paragraph? Is this opinion based?

  Such argumentative language sets one up for having the post understood as a rant rather than an attempt to improve the question. A reading of it can easily be "I have this question, I think it should be open, you all are wrong." and garnered votes in agreement or disagreement with such a reading. If the post was written in a way that used fewer multiple punctuation marks and emotional language it might not have been downvoted.  Further realize that the OP has had a number of other questions in the past 24h that are scored -19, -12, and -29 as of this writing including one titled "I think Stack Overflow sucks and I want to complain about it. What is the proper way of doing this?" Such recent notoriety may lead to downvotes meaning "quit wasting our time with your rants".

Note that all of the above posts are tagged as discussion, rather than support.

Comment: Having a hard time finding reasons not to downvote any of those examples :/

Comment: @Will there's a reason I didn't link them beyond the search... meta effect on meta?

Comment: THIS! At the end of the day, crap is still crap and should neither be ignored nor encouraged no matter what. I concur with the bulk of the downvotes being cast.

Comment: Let's not forget though that your search will not take deleted questions into account and many of these border-line questions that [I am referring to](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta#comment100294_272607) may have been deleted by the author because they were unfamiliar enough with the site to not know.  I have no evidence that they were though.

Comment: @psubsee2003 for a down voted question to get deleted it would also have to be closed.  If it was closed as a dup, it was likely down voted for lack of (re)searching.  If it was not closed as a dup, it is a question of if it should even have been asked on meta in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelT not if the OP deleted it.  Yes lack of research is certainly a valid reason to downvote any question.  I do that myself.  But there is still support questions that aren't duplicates and are not always the easiest to research, or are about getting feedback specific question or specific review.

Comment: @psubsee2003 those are very difficult to track down. Self deletes don't show up in the 10k tools for recently deleted. You would need to probably ask SE for such examples of self deleted negative scored posts (and a 10k view to it?) and see if they were justifiably down voted for some reason.

Comment: @MichaelT I know and I wasn't asking you to look.  I was only mentioning that to point out a deleted question will not be there.  Maybe I am missing the point of your answer, but you seem to be suggesting that there may not be a voting culture problem because most of the downvoted support questions are justified and I was just offering a possible explanation as to why I don't necessarily think this is a complete picture of what Stijn is talking about.

Comment: It's exceedingly rare in my recollection for an asker to delete a question on Meta before it gets closed, @psubsee2003.

Comment: I think the most annoying cases are where the OP asks specifically what was wrong with something he/she did and *how to improve next time*. Sometimes they get downvoted even when they demonstrate that they have searched for an answer already. When I see these sorts of specific-question questions downvoted I, too, feel like we are undermining the purpose of the Meta site. These people are asking how to improve, what's to disagree with about that?

Comment: @eddie_cat some examples would be helpful.  I'm not saying it doesn't happen, but specific examples would be useful in identifying where the process of meta voting either broke, or helping people try to write better meta posts.  Note also that many times the *tone* of the question is getting down voted.  "What the heck is wrong with this post? How is this opinion based?!?!?!" doesn't set the atmosphere for trying to be constructive in answers or up votes.  I must also point out that your example in the question is tagged discussion, not support.

Comment: Here are some examples I found with a quick look at the past several pages of Meta -- http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272333/deleted-answer-dont-understand-why, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272073/question-on-hold-as-off-topic-asking-for-research, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271906/can-i-crosspost-to-stackoverflow-a-question-that-was-barely-seen-on-dba, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272602/what-is-wrong-with-this-question-about-asking-for-the-proper-html-tag-for-a-give IMO none of these really present anything to "disagree" with

Comment: I wasn't really meaning to only present "support" questions, as I think the discussion ones apply here as well.

Comment: Good examples, @eddie_cat; thanks for finding those.

Comment: @eddie_cat edited with my understanding of those down votes.

Comment: "Can I crosspost to stackoverflow a question that was barely seen on DBA?" I would just rename the title to "Are there disadvantages of crossposting..." or "What is are the rules saying about..." and according to the logic in this answer all downvotes should never happen. The problem: My intuition tells me, they would have happened anyway. But anyway as a pro-tip: always pose Meta question as neutral wisdom seeking statements and give your opinion in an answer. Theoretically this should prevent all kind of bad effects on the question.

Answer (score 4):

I posted this as a comment in a question elsewhere on Meta.SO, and it got a fair number of upvotes, so I'm repeating/expanding it here.

**This is a side-effect of up/downvotes not affecting reputation on per-site Metas, which gives different meaning to the score on a Meta question.**

Downvotes on a question on Meta often mean "I disagree with your point of view", not "This is a bad question" as they're supposed to on the main site.

Checking your profile, it looks like you spend almost all your time on StackOverflow, Meta.SO, and Meta.SE - so you might not have seen this behavior prior to the Meta.SO and Meta.SE split.

Before the split, when Meta.SO *did* have its own reputation system independent of SO, it did not exhibit this behavior.  Now, however, users are simply acting more and more like they would on a regular site-specific Meta.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't exhibit this behavior?  I see very few differences in voting habits since the split.

Comment: @Servy It wasn't nearly as pronounced as it is now, and my expectation is that it'll get even moreso as time goes on.  It mostly happens to the questions that, read like like the asker is already skewed towards a certain opinion

Comment: As a very active meta user both before and after the split, I've seen very few changes at all (with respect to this behavior), and wouldn't expect to see much changing going forward.  People were bringing up this exact issue regularly long before the split.  It's nothing new, or even particularly exaggerated.

Comment: I think the key point emphasized here is that voting is different on meta.  Rather than strict shows research or not, you can voice your approval or disapproval regardless of how well the question is structured, articulated or researched.

Comment: The downvotes are because people disagree with your point of view ;p

Comment: @Neo It's currently +2/-4; some people agree.  And you can't downvote a comment, like the one I mention at the start, so it's not like I was expecting everyone to agree

Comment: @Izkata, I upvoted your answer. It's brave of you to highlight that SO has a problem. Look how you are losing reputation just for expressing your correct opinion.

Comment: @Neo Except I'm not losing any reputation.  That's my point; people act differently on per-site Metas because of that difference in design.

Comment: Yes, totally agree with you - votes on meta are cheap and flow freely. So I quite freely gave you +1 unicorn points, and took -1 away from the OP because I don't see his issue as being a problem on meta.