# Why was one of my comments deleted?

Tags: discussion

In this post: [What is the use of 0-length array (or std::array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26209190/what-is-the-use-of-0-length-array-or-stdarray)

I posted a comment about some of the uses of a 0-length array. Why was it deleted?
I wasn't notified and only noticed by accident. If I did something wrong, at least explain it to me so I can learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was deleted because it was flagged.

Why was it flagged?

Well, it looks like your comment was made in relation to another comment that had already been deleted, so your comment was flagged as obsolete.

Why was *that* one deleted? Because it was apparently a joke.

Comment: Ok. It would have been nice to modify my comment not to refer to the deleted comment. It stood alone.

Comment: @NeilKirk - moderators don't really have time to edit comments - unless it's really obvious what the edit should be.

Comment: Then they shouldn't be trigger-happy, deleting comments that add value. It discourages people from contributing to the site. I have seen over-aggressive moderation many times.

Comment: @Kartick we don't just delete without checking first. However, if something is truly useful it should be either edited into the question or answer or be added as an answer in its own right.

Comment: Hmm... I understand and appreciate that the mods are doing their best. I guess deleting a comment makes it harder for the person who posted the comment to incorporate it into an answer. This is because deleted comments are not visible even to the person who posted them. And because they don't even know that their comment got deleted.