# Get notification when 50 question limit passes?

Tags: support, post-ban, notifications, rate-limiting

I am experiencing the [50 question per month limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit) on Stack Overflow. I'd like to get a notification when the limit passes, however, looking at the *Subscription* portion of my profile, I don't see how to create it:

[image]

How can I create a notification when the limit passes?

Comment: It has nothing to do with points, as you say. It has to do with the lack of effort you're spending in trying to arrive at a solution before posting here. With an average of 2 questions a day, presuming an 8 hour day, you're spending less than 4 hours average doing your own research before just bailing out and posting here. I've done 4 days (and longer) to search for a solution or try to arrive at one myself, and 99% of the time I can figure it out and don't need to post here. (You can check my profile here to see what I've asked and what I've answered for others.)

Comment: It's a legit question, with a legit answer ("track it yourself"). Purging the side discussion; [it's easy to fall on your face here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617).

Comment: Have you considered that it's *undesirable* to notify you that you could now post another question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - the use case is not clear to me. I seem to have that now. Perhaps there's some facet I don't understand?

Comment: @jww it's not clear what you're trying to ask me. However, maybe this will answer it: the point of the rate limit is to *change your behaviour*, make you spend more time figuring things out yourself and post fewer, higher-quality questions. If you're just sitting twiddling your thumbs waiting to be able to post the same questions you would anyway, what's the point? 50 is supposed to be an outer limit to indicate the very worst cases, you should be **nowhere near that**.

Comment: Agree with @Shog9. Totally legit question. Voted to reopen

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Perhaps you can name a few questions I asked that you find offensive or I should not have asked? Otherwise, its just theoretical [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe - issue resolved. There's no need for the question since its been re-opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I create a notification when the ban is lifted?

I'm pretty sure there is no option to get notified by SE when your question ban has ended.

You could manually go to your questions page in your profile, find where 30 days ago was, and then count the number of questions you asked since that day till now. Once you can go back 30 days and count less than 50 questions since then <sup>*(and add on any deleted questions since last 30 days, if any*)</sup>, that's when you should be able to ask another question.

> It's a sliding window, @hobbes, if that's what you're asking. If I asked 48 questions in the last 30 days, I can ask two today. –  Shog9♦ , [src](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit#comment353092_89230)

Screenshot from your [questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=2)

[image]

So I think since today is July 29th UTC, that those 3 questions you asked on June 29th should roll off sometime today or tomorrow, then you'd be able to ask 3 new questions.

Comment: FWIW, there's no "end of ban date" tracked within the system; it just checks how many questions were created since `getdate()-30` and if that's >= 50 you can't ask more. So any notification would be somewhat inaccurate anyway; you'd be better off just setting a timer.

Comment: @Shog9 - Today, I was not not allowed to ask a question. The system told me that. Some time in the future, I will be able to ask a question again. I'd like the system to notify me when the time comes. If I get banned again and attempt to ask a question, then rinse, lather, repeat... Its really not as difficult as you are making it sound.

Comment: Depends on how you define difficult, @jww. Conceptually, it's not complicated - which is why you can easily figure it out for yourself. Practically though, implementing it would affect maybe a half-dozen users a day; that'd be a pretty expensive notification for what is currently rather cheap logic. Most similar notifications (say, bounties) are raised on a schedule (a query run at the top of the hour, maybe) - so they're late by up to an hour; to beat our "set a reminder" method would require an even more expensive system. Again, for a tiny, tiny handful of users who can't just sleep on it.

Comment: @Shog9 just out of curiousity, about what percentage of members would such a change benefit directly?

Comment: Don't particularly feel like calculating a rigorous answer to that, @santiago; you can assume whatever minute fraction of a percent appeals to you and probably not be wrong. It's > 0, but not by very much.