# Why does a high rep user have a better chance of getting an answer than a low rep user?

Tags: feature-request

I was reading through all the privileges, when I figured out that offering bounties was a privilege. Now I am going to just put a situation:

> **User with 70 rep:** The user posts a question, and it doesn't receive enough attention and eventually no answer. To attract attention, the user wants to post a bounty but does not have enough rep. Finally they get no solution.
>
> **User with 1k rep:** The user posts the same question, it doesn't receive enough attention and no answer. The user offers a bounty, and gets an answer.
>
> **Finally:** User with 1k rep got an answer to the same question while the 70 rep user did not.

SO was supposed to be a website which gives answers to its questioners, no matter what their reputation is.

That's why the system was created in which you can offer bounty's on other users' questions, but if nobody does that in this case, it becomes unfair.

This was problem 1. Now problem 2 is when a user with low rep, even if they have the privilege, does not want to offer a bounty, as then they will lose most of their reputation. Thus, I have hardly seen users <300 rep, offering bounty's. Bounties were made to promote questions, but low rep users will not do that.

Comment: Why the downvote? please explain.

Comment: You don't seem to be requesting a feature in your feature request.

Comment: @TZHX, it is in my answer.

Comment: The answer is meant to be a *response*, not the whole point of the post.

Comment: Do you have links to your example questions, by the way?

Comment: Please read: [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/4639281) It has a lot of information about what we expect from feature requests, and posts on meta in general.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have that thought. Personally, I don't really look at the reputation when I want to answer a question.

Probably you are talking about the users whom certainly didn't read the SO guide on asking. Like the questions of the following form:

- "*code for me*".

That's not the purpose of SO.

- "*why/how is that ...* "

Most of these kind of questions can be answered directly by a simple google search. Or using the SO search tool.

However, it can be obvious that a high rep user could have answers. I am not sure how you have determined it. I can find two reasons of your conclusions:

- **Reason 1:** You're checking questions and see that it got asked by user with rep over x #reps.

Have you checked the date? If the question is old, it could happen that people upvoted the question because they had the same question and were happy to see that question. With an answer of course.

- **Reason 2:** Newest questions of high rep users got answered while those from low rep users aren't.

The rep usually shows the experience of the user on the SO site. They know how to formulate a question. Good questions get answered more easily than bad ones (see the two examples here above). Newest users sometimes don't know to formulate their question well. Code formatting problems aren't a big issue, but show that *way* of asking is wrong.

Either they don't bother to take effort in writing a question or they didn't give a fuck (sorry for the language) about the "How to ask" guide.

Now, your suggestions (which is in an answer ...):

> **Solution to problem 1:** Each user gets a free bounty of 50 rep in which none of his reputation gets deducted but he cannot award the bounty on itself. If he wastes that, its his mistake.

They can simply create a new account to bypass that.

> **Solution to problem 2:** For users having less than 300 rep (or everyone), there should be an option of offering a 25 rep bounty. Because of this, low rep users will not feel that they have lost most of their reputation.

I don't agree again here. 300 rep is nothing, easy to achieve.

The reason of providing bounties is for pointing to **interesting** questions. Not an assignment question. Or "poor" questions...

Comment: I love your typically Belgian profile pic. Beer, choclate and waffles, what more does someone need? :P

Answer (score 19):

> SO was supposed to be a website which gives answers to its questioners

Misconception. Stack Overflow is meant as a resource containing great questions and answers, where the question being asked preferably is **not** something that OP is currently stuck with. The person who is asking the question is irrelevant indeed.

If low-rep users wanting to *"get their damn problem fixed right now"* would actually read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), we'd have 98% less question being asked and people more motivated towards maintaining the quality of the content, as opposed to answering every *"This code doesn't work, help me"* dump in the hopes of getting some fake internet points.

Comment: *where the question being asked preferably is **not** something that OP is currently stuck with* -- I don't think this is accurate (or perhaps it is misstated). [The Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) explicitly says that questions should be based on "actual problems that you face," which implies that at least some good questions will be something the OP is currently stuck with. What's really important is not that the asker be irrelevant but that the problem be encountered frequently enough that the asker *becomes* irrelevant *in comparison to* the volume of future readers.

Comment: @Air keywords being _"currently stuck with"_. Most great questions in my opinion do not start out of acute problems, but rather genuine interest.

Comment: Genuine interest in the absence of a real problem can be [just as underwhelming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/2359271) as "help I am not good with compiler" questions.

Comment: @Air the scores on that question are a prime example for the reason I call upvotes "likes". It does however take nothing away from my stance on _"Help, my code broke! Need help ASAP!"_ questions.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the sentence that epitomizes OP's confusion, but I agree with @Air that your "not something that OP is currently stuck with" comment is not really helpful.

Answer (score -45):

**Solution to problem 1:** Each user gets a free bounty of 50 rep in which none of his reputation gets deducted but he cannot award the bounty on itself. If he wastes that, its his mistake.

**Solution to problem 2:** For users having less than 300 rep (or everyone), there should be an option of offering a 25 rep bounty. Because of this, low rep users will not feel that they have lost most of their reputation.

Comment: You can wrap that as suggestion in your request here above.

Comment: So, every single use account asking a homework / no effort question puts a bounty on their unanswered crash dump nullpointer question. This stops it being closed for a week and increases their chance of getting a response even though it really shouldn't.

Comment: You should put the requested feature *in* your feature request post.