# Answer ban on my first evening with three down-votes answers?

Tags: support

I just registered today and answered some questions. Some of these answers got downvoted for no clear reason and now I can't answer any more. That feels not very welcoming. I wonder what I could do about it? Just move on and leave SO behind? Maybe...

Edit:
This question got two downvotes already, too. I think some people really don't like new ones here so I will go my way. Thanks to everyone who communicated with me.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, many of their contributions aren't half bad. A part of the problem is that it can be very difficult for a new user to gauge what we here deem a "good question"; answers on "bad questions" (like, ones that are too broad, inherently subjective, etc.) can get downvoted simply because of the quality of the question.

Comment: For starters, don't answer crap like [Website returning and displaying file depending on input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777464/website-returning-and-displaying-file-depending-on-input).  Stack Overflow does not exist to try to answer every question possible.

Comment: As per your edit: [required reading about voting on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/4639281)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your answers, you have answered several questions that have lots of down votes and some of the questions you answered have now been closed. These down votes may have not been there when you answered the question, however, as a new user you should think twice before posting an answer on a down voted question. There are often issues with these questions and it is generally difficult to give a high quality answer to this type of questions. It might be possible to provide a high quality answer to a low quality question, however, the down voter didn't believe that was the case for your answer.

Comment: I understand what you saying. But isn't that hilarious? I have an answer for a question one asked and a third one can put me down because he  don't likes the question or think its a stupid one? ... That sounds very hilarious. But ok. Then i'll use my time on other websites, no problem.

Comment: @bloodstix Stack Overflow has a lot of very strict rules on what is on topic and what isn't. To most folks around here this is the reason why the place has 10 million questions, but still maintains to manage a semblance of quality. If that doesn't work for you, you may indeed have to look for other places on the web

Comment: As i was not asking but answering questions ... and not even "wrong" in some stupid way. Yeah well, sounds rude but .. i should try to find people who appreciate my help. Thanks.

Comment: @bloodstix Correctness is only one aspect of the quality of the answer.  There are many more.  An answer doesn't need to be wrong to be bad, and it isn't necessarily good just because it's correct.

Comment: @bloodstix in addition to encouraging people to ask bad off-topic questions by giving them answers, you should also encourage spammers by posting testimonials on their posts.  Not enough people are doing their part to encourage help vampires and spammers, so kudos to you!

Comment: +1 to bloodstix. This community is so hostile to newcomers. Forget for a moment the quality of the answers, which I'm sure will be debated here 1000X over. Why would he/she continue to contribute if this is the attitude on day 1? What kind of user onboarding is that?

Answer (score 23):

I've had a skim through some of your less well received answers, and in all honesty, there are a few problems:

- You're attempting to answer questions which really do not belong on the site, like "learning resources for PHP" ([here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777630/learning-resources-to-create-social-media-site-in-php) for 10K+)
- Your answers are elongated comments ([as an example - now 10K only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34774950/1079354))
- Your answers aren't cohesive ([as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34772542/1079354))

One of the main things you want to do when answering a question is to **be assertive.**  You're regarded as a subject matter expert when answering, so you should answer as such.  Feel more confident in your answer.  If there's not enough information for you to answer a question, **run away!**  Until you can comment everywhere, that question cannot be safely answered by you, so don't attempt to until the OP decides to clarify.

Also, **don't use answers as comments.** They're meant for answers, not a discussion box.

Take a little break and reflect on your answers, and look around at others' answers on the site.  See what you could improve on when responding, and be sure that your answer is clear, concise, and above all, **correct**.

Comment: Your last 2 examples of my answers have true facts in them? One of them was even accepted as correct? I didn't know that just 100% perfect answers are allowed. I thought this is a place to help others and find help.

Comment: @bloodstix: There is still a standard of quality here.  I realize that Stack Overflow is a complicated beast, but the OP isn't telling you that you're wrong; it's the rest of the community that is.  I strongly encourage you to have a read of some of the top answers here, and make note of their style and approach.  Also, be sure that you understand [what is acceptable to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) so you're not caught up in this same situation again; you don't want to be punished because you're answering a poor question (which is what's happening).

Answer (score 19):

I think time is also a factor here. The answer ban is meant to slow down new users who are contributing a number of low-quality or potentially inappropriate answers. You've contributed 11 answers in 5 hours, with none of them being upvoted and four being downvoted.

You should have been given a warning as you approached the level where you might be temporarily banned, but you might have been posting quickly enough that it didn't have time to warn you.

Like I said, there's a bit of a time component to this, so I don't think you're permanently banned. I think you'll naturally come out of this in a little while, but I'd use the time to look into your answers and why they might have been downvoted. A few tweaks might be all you need to improve the voting on them and get you clear of this.

Answer (score 4):

As a new user, you might want to slow down and get a feel for the culture of the site before diving in and answering a ton of questions. Many factors go into good writing beyond being factually correct, and understanding the audience and the context/culture you're writing in are key.

As for *this* question getting down-voted... Your tone is one of self-pity and accusation: threatening to leave S.O. because you got down-voted; accusing members of not being welcoming to new users. Sorry to be blunt, but it's not endearing.

Comment: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).