# Allow us again to see if a question is currently on the close review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

What is in the close vote review queue is nebulous. We are asked to reduce it but know not what it is.

On the timeline, users could see if the posts have pending reviews tasks. However, yesterday this information was replaced in the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items) with only completed reviews.

I ask that we can see both active and completed reviews from the timeline, or, if that is not possible, that the timeline functionality is restored to show the active review on a post.

I realize there are cons for this information, but am asking for a feature request to expose it.

Comment: What are you asking to be restored?  What are you asking to be exposed? Your feature request isn't very clear. I might suggest reading [Shog's advice on asking for features](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617).

Comment: The information that a post is in the queue

Comment: That doesn't really help clarify this.  What information? What do you need? What do you want?  If you expect us to take a request seriously, you need to offer a few more details.

Comment: The organization hid the information yesterday. That did not help to clarify what is in the queue blue.

Comment: @bluefeet on the timeline, users could see if the posts have pending reviews tasks, Drew is asking for that power back.

Comment: It was confusing as all get out to have just the in-progress reviews in the timeline, and I don't see why it would be any better to have in-progress reviews in the timeline with the completed. Completed reviews show a _history_ of the post. In-progress reviews give little to no useful information.

Comment: @Kendra actually, it was useful for me: to whip reviews in the right places to end up with the right actions. Like deleting an obvious NAA before roboreviewers invalidate the review hitting "looks ok"

Comment: In my opinion we need a status call for a question. We write bots and try to steer. The change yesterday hid that effort.

Comment: @Braiam I could see it being useful in that case, I suppose. The instance I and another couple of users ran into was a "duplicate" closure on a question. The question was _flagged_ and in review, but the timeline showed the review and said "close" so other users thought it meant the question had been closed when it hadn't. It took a couple minutes to sort out what had happened. I suppose it would be less confusing with the review _not_ disappearing, with question closure reviews, the feature doesn't seem like it would be useful...

Comment: I would like to see more details here about how you plan to use this for bots.

Comment: I am happy to provide that @Shog9

Comment: @Kendra I always have read it as "in review: close".

Comment: I personally used that information for 2 things: 1. tracking if an answer was in the VLQRQ so that I can flag it or not (I flag a lot)  2. Editing posts in the Close Vote queue to get them out of it.

Comment: You ask us to reduce the queue size. Then you take the information away.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The point of this answer is to show what you could previously do when, in the timeline, you could access the review queue of a question or answer if it had an active review.

With a [userscript](https://github.com/Gothdo/UserScripts/blob/master/so-review-links.user.js) developed by [Gothdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853934/gothdo), you could display in the page if the question or answer was present in a review queue.

> Why was this nice from a moderation point of view?

The knowledge about a **question** being in a close review queue helps you with:

1. If the question should be closed and was obviously bad with already 4 CV then you could decide to not vote (leave it to review), saving a close vote.
2. If you had an insight that would improve a question, you could open the review and edit it from there, ending the close review.
3. If you saw question had been improved, you could open the review and choose "leave open" or edit it out of queue

The knowledge about an **answer** being in the low quality review queue:

1. Avoid flagging the answer since it is already in the queue. There are 10K users using [New Answers to Old Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) interface and they get quickly out of flags, hence this was a way to save flags.
2. If you saw an answer in the queue then you could enter and edit it out (note the [LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) tends to delete many apples, yes they have holes but still are apples)

This is a **screenshot of the interface** before the update of the timeline

[image: Interface]

Probably this could also be misused. The purpose of this post is not evaluating if the review queue should be exposed (if so to which user rep level). I'm simply showing what you could achieve and how you could use this when actively trying to moderate SO.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that Petter :p   ... No one here wants to misuse anything

Comment: @Drew That I know, the point is to display why the previous time line was good for moderation. I know people will comment about all possible misuse and I do not really want this discussion, so they shoule post an own answer and let this answer remain as only a demonstration of what could be achieved previously

Comment: I can see now how this can be useful. However, a post was status-declined yesterday that [was asking for a similar feature to be built in.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176131/link-to-review-on-post) Something tells me that if reasons other than just this aren't given, this'll stay how it is now because of that.

Comment: @Kendra Thanks for the link to that other post. I think it was lacking in a clear use case, so I'd hesitate to consider it a conclusive response.

Comment: @Kendra, yes I know since they status-completed this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275795/should-the-new-timeline-view-show-links-to-review-items, hence the timing of Drew's post. I should maybe have posted on those post, but you can't always know everything that is happening on SO, until its to late... or may be not?

Comment: The flip side of that is that I can't really know about some gist that relies on an undocumented feature unless someone links to it somewhere... ([stackapps](http://stackapps.com) is always a good choice!)

Comment: The flip flip side is that we cannot rely on stuff if you flip it off

Answer (score 16):

[Petter has helpfully explained what you actually wanted this for](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319682/allow-us-again-to-see-if-a-question-is-currently-on-the-close-review-queues/319692#319692), so I'll address the uses he raised:

1. **Not voting / not flagging**. I'm not sure this is a great idea; it actually changes the behavior of review. Obviously, not close-voting means the question won't be closed as quickly, which is problematic if you want to prevent answers (if that's *not* what you want, you shouldn't be close voting anyway). But there's a more subtle effect for Low Quality review: fewer flags means [fewer "looks ok" reviews are required to resolve the task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). The root problem here is that we have essentially two parallel review interfaces, the one under /review and the old one in the 10K tools... And you're stepping on each others' toes. This was a hacky solution to that, but I'm sympathetic to the problem.
2. **You don't have to be in review to edit.** There are inconsistencies in terms of the effect this has (it'll resolve VLQ flags but not NAA or close flags for instance), but the hardest part is finding someone willing to make "salvage edits" *at all*. If this is something folks are interested in doing more of, an explicit "save this awful post" tool would be ideal.
3. **Leave open**. This one is a bit dodgy. [I've resisted in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151476/allow-voting-vote-to-not-close-from-the-question-without-being-in-a-review) efforts to make "leave open" a first-class means of interacting with a question, as in that context it becomes just a way to remove others' ability to review a specific post. I may be wrong on this; still, giving this ability to folks who know the secret route without making it available to everyone is *definitely* unfair.

I don't have a great solution to #1 in mind, I'm afraid. But it would probably involve some substantive improvements to the 10K tools. Some folks have been experimenting with userscripts to make the "late answers" list more useful recently, and I'm interested to hear what they're able to identify when it comes to problems that are being missed in the current /review interface. For their purposes (which is to say, as a temporary work-around to the removal of the review links) I'll note that you can accomplish the same task by checking for the presence of a "very low quality" option in the flagging dialogue on posts scoring <=0 - if it exists, then the post isn't currently in review.

For #2, I'd like to see an option for privileged users to go directly to a "review circumventing" editor. Essentially, they'd be trusted to actually *fix* a post, and their edit would immediately remove it from review just as editing from *within* review does. This idea needs some fleshing out, but I think it would go a lot further than a non-obvious option on a hidden route by giving folks with the most experience a chance to salvage questions they have a particular interest in.

Usage #3 I would really prefer wasn't available. Quite honestly, this by itself is good reason not to restore access to pending reviews. You can try and convince me I'm wrong here, but do so by arguing for an option available to everyone - this shouldn't be a secret.

Comment: I wonder if there could be a middle ground: allowing questions with an MCVE or substantial explanation edited into them to somehow escape the queue, while still not allowing a general "leave open" feature which can be used to hinder reviews...

Comment: Yeah, I'd support a strong option to dequeue if coupled with an edit. Folks who aren't willing to do more than click a button aren't expressing a very strong opinion.

Comment: This is no answer to the question

Comment: The problem is that most low-quality questions which can be improved, need improvement by OP (either including a previously missing MCVE, or just adding two more paragraphs of explanation). So the edit and the review action would be decoupled in most of these cases, and I have a hunch this would be typical for questions in the close review queue. If you weren't implying that an "edit+dequeue" option would be plausible, then sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: Saying the OP can improve a question is meaningless, @Andras - in theory, it's true; it's their question, unless it's been answered they can change it to whatever they want. In practice, if they didn't write a good question the first time around only a tiny fraction will ever fix them, and they're not really an objective 3rd-party anyway so letting them review their own questions isn't a good idea. For questions that *can* be answered, but are still asked poorly enough to make it into review... There's real value in opening the door to folks who are up for making "heroic" edits.

Comment: OK, I understand now, thanks. Then we're talking about two different things. I think there's a significant amount of initially-low-quality posts which are edited by OP before being closed, so they (ideally) stop gathering votes, but then they stick in the queue for two weeks. If we could remove *these*, we could slim down the CVQ. But I know that devising a mechanism which would allow *only* these posts to leave the queue is far from trivial (if possible at all).

Comment: Strictly-speaking, the thing you wrote up top isn't a question either, @Drew. Heck, it's not even a question in more loosely-defined terms. This is meta; we do things other than Q&A here. [You may wish to take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) before participating further.

Comment: A few years back, we investigated the idea of making edits themselves count as a "leave open" review, @Andras. As I recall, it wouldn't have made a significant difference, although things may have changed since then. Regardless, the situation you describe is what *vote aging* is intended to address - if a question stops getting votes, it drops to the bottom of the queue and eventually drops out entirely.

Comment: You asked us to remove stuff from the close vote review queue. Then you remove information that can help us do that. Then you (dare I suggest) attack me that this is not a question. Then I get a bluefeet message that is teetering on a ban. Maybe this is the way you want to treat your peeps. I would suggest otherwise

Answer (score 11):

Here is what I do. I focus people on stuff that can close now. Close vote count of 3,4.

The [Campaigns](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/95290) room. We can doubly close stuff. Last nite with very little effort we closed a bunch in Python with no effort. We just went out and asked a few people, nicely.

Part of our struggle is just asking people to do stuff. And mods accepting that.

Half the problem is gaining acceptance. We close half your questions like it or not.

As for the queue status of a given question. Well we need to know. If it does not need to be in the queue, we ought to know.

If a question needs to be edited and thus removed from the queue, then I am all in favor of it. That is all I am saying.

Comment: I've found your campaigns very helpful (for finding close-worthy questions in the R tag) and find it strange that this answer has no comments (presumably because they were expunged) and that Shog answered as if your use-case is a mystery, even though it's fairly clearly described right here.