# VLQ Queue - Add votes for users flagging post

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I propose that the user flagging a post as VLQ or NAA, should (if they have the required reputation points to cast a delete vote in the queue, 2000) add one vote towards the "Recommended Deletion" total needed to remove a question/answer.

**Please note: This is similar to, but not a delete vote cast by a user with > 10k reputation points.**

If they're recommending it, I don't see why this shouldn't be the case. Multiple users flagging the post, would get the question removed faster, and even if only a single user reports it, it would cause one less vote to be needed in order to remove a post.

I also feel this way, because if a user is flagging a post that is already in the queue, their flag is partially wasted (it's already in the queue, so nothing actually happens other than helpful/disputed depending on which way the queue decides). What I'm proposing would give that flag additional merit, because if they came across this post in the VLQ post queue, they would vote the same way.

More clarification:

1. Users with 15-1999 reputation points: No change
2. Users with 2000-19999 reputation points: Upon flagging a post VLQ or NAA, if it would enter the VLQ review queue, instead it enters the review queue with one more "Recommended Deletion" vote already cast. (I say "one more" because a post flagged as VLQ will wait 15 minutes before entering the VLQ queue to give the user a chance to edit that post. If multiple users flag as VLQ, it should enter the queue with that many votes.) If it's already in the VLQ review queue, instead of having no effect, it would cast one "Recommended Deletion" vote on the post in question.
3. Users with 20k reputation points: Still a little bit fuzzy, as I haven't reached this level yet, but I think it should work exactly like #2. Flagging a post as VLQ or NAA should not consume a delete vote, as it will be reviewed by others and acted on as such.

Comment: Recommending deletion in the LQPRQ when you have enough rep to vote to delete actually does cast a delete vote

Comment: I think you read my question wrong @TinyGiant: I'm talking about when I flag a post as VLQ or NAA. It does not cast a delete vote in this case (Between 2k rep and 10k rep). I'm not quite sure what happens >= 10k.

Comment: But you would not have the cast delete vote on answers privilege... are you asking for the ability to cast delete votes on answers specifically in the LQPRQ whether or not you have the privilege?

Comment: Yes. At 2k rep, you have the ability to "Recommend Deletion", which isn't quite the same as casting a delete vote. At 6 "Recommend Deletion" votes, it's either deleted (<=0 rep I believe), or mod flagged for possible removal. I'm saying that a person with 2k rep, should add one "Recommended Deletion" vote towards the final 6 needed to remove the post.

Comment: This is some what related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319682/allow-us-again-to-see-if-a-question-is-currently-on-the-close-review-queues , since it allowed you to access the que (>2k) and review from there. [status-declined]. To allow people with only flag rep delete posts seems a bit dangerous, the LQP que is already deleting to much stuff but at least sometimes we find it and stop it.

Comment: You want that a VLQ/NAA flag essentially counts as a half delete vote? So 6 privileged flags would cause the post to be deleted? (btw the delete vote privilege is 20k, not 10k)

Comment: What would be the behavior for 20K'ers?  Would flagging VLQ or NAA consume one of our delete votes?  I would not like that.  I would be okay with it counting as a recommend delete vote.

Comment: Correct @Floem: I clarified in the later paragraph. Basically, the jist is: If I came across this post in the VLQ queue, I would have already clicked "Recommend Deletion". Why not simply add it through the flagging interface as well?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm not quite sure how the flagging interface currently works for users that can cast delete votes. I would assume it would work the same.

Comment: @FrankerZ It is the same for non 20k-ers.  The difference is that in the LQPQ we get a delete button until we run out of delete votes.  So if you want to "default action" applied then flagging would start costing us delete votes which I would not be a fan of.

Comment: Not sure I've quite got this, but are you saying that in effect, the same behaviour for the RD/D votes in the queue should apply on the flag that puts it in the queue? eg: Effectively it enters review with one review already completed (as if the user flagging it had reviewed it and said delete?)

Comment: @JonClements I've added another tidbit providing some more information. Yes to what you mentioned, but also adding additional "Recommended Deletion" votes, if it's already in a queue.

Comment: @FrankerZ the problem with #3 is the uncertainty as a user won't know if the post is in a queue or not. So you might flag it to put it into the queue, which'll automatically cast a RD (if I'm understanding you correctly) - what happens then if you do cast a delete vote - does it cancel out the recommended vote? Seems a bit odd as doing it through review will have different behaviour. I think it's getting a little complicated here...

Comment: Related, I think, in spirit: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323946/

Comment: @JoshCaswell you're correct - but reading FrankerZ's points - I've interpreted #3 as that should be the requested behaviour if a post is already in a review queue and a flag is cast outside the queue...

Comment: With #3: Because I'm unfamiliar with how the system currently works, it's hard for me to comment, but I would assume if you cast a delete vote, it wouldn't change the "Recommended Deletion" vote in the low quality review queue, as you still want that post deleted.

Comment: @FrankerZ at 20k - it casts *actual* delete votes - so having #3 behave as #2 would be differing behaviour between using review and flagging on a post that may or may not be in review. Also, as said in comments here, it probably won't go down well that 20k users casting a flag that they think is putting it in a queue will automatically use one of their delete votes where applicable...

Comment: If I'm reading things correctly from [this Meta.SE post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue), flagging as VLQ/NAA adds 1 to the number of "Looks OK" reviews required to clear the flag (either as declined or disputed). In that sense, it may be enough: instead of reducing the time it takes to delete the post from review, the current behaviour is to increase the time it takes to keep it.

Comment: Sounds more like you want fewer 'recommend delete' reviews required, which... sounds like a bad idea, from what I've seen. I wouldn't mind having *more* required. LQP deletes plenty of stuff already.

Comment: How often does the LQP delete things that shouldn't warrant deleting @undo? I think, from what I've read, that they're not deleting enough. And the idea isn't to reduce the number of "Recommended delete" reviews required, it's to count the flaggers opinion as a vote. If you feel more should be required, then up it to 7 votes required to delete, and allow flaggers to count towards the vote. (This would keep the # of votes the same (Albeit increase them for flaggers < 2k rep), but count other flags as votes toward deletion too. (Visible content would be deleted faster, as more flags)

Comment: It deletes things often enough to prompt [me to write a plea for sanity](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/1849664). I still see it being far too delete-happy, especially judging from the disputed-low-quality-review flags we get.

Comment: @undo So how do you feel about my 7 vote solution? Would require 1 more vote from a 2k+ member, and allow 2k+ flaggers to cast votes on the current audit in process.

Comment: @FrankerZ At that point, why not just require another vote and be done with it? I see no reason to speed up LQP, it's already plenty fast.

Comment: I just hate the idea that flaggers of a post already in the queue have their flag pretty much wasted.