# The flag menu needs improvement

Tags: discussion, flags, user-interface

I think that the flag menus need to be improved. There are a number of [why was my flag declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+flag+declined) and [we need to be able to move stuff to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=more+migration+option) and "stop shoveling crap to Code Review" questions that might be preventable in the future. Flagging should be quick, no more than a minute.

### The ability to migrate should be migrated

- The current menu has no information. "You may be able to get help on Super User" suggests that every question with the close reason is on-topic on SU.
- Let's add the help center info for destinations in the dialog and remove "get help on SU/SF".
- The too old to migrate appears next to "off topic because..." and it's confusing.
- Let's put "too old to migrate" beside "belongs on another SE site" option. Currently, the option silently disappears, but it would be easy to just have it not selectable.

### The off-topic menu is off

- Opinion-based questions are considered off-topic, yet are not under "off-topic".
- Let's move "opinion-based" to off-topic.

Comment: I think you're much more likely to get a good robust discussion going if you limit your question to one issue that stands out that you want to fix. You can ask multiple questions; but with a question this long, any points that you'd like explained or debated probably won't be because there's so much to cover here.

Comment: you had me at the title...

Comment: @Shog9 But it flaws off to sinking in the quicksand unfortunately.

Comment: @Shog9 ... and lost me on the third paragraph.

Comment: Much of this is certainly worthy of discussion, but should, as George already said, be distributed across a number of questions rather than one for all.

Comment: Is it better now? I removed a lot of stuff and it fits on one screen. What's left is essentially just 3 suggestions to move or reword different things.

Comment: *Let's add the help center info for destinations in the dialog.* - I think as its own feature request, you wouldn't find a lot of opposition to this one.

Comment: I think if you make each of the three suggestions its own feature request it won't be too broad.

Comment: @BSMP Is it bad to flood meta with 3 consecutive posts?

Comment: @Laurel if they're well written I wouldn't think so.

Answer (score 11):

I think we can all agree, the flag dialog is terrible. It's a compromise solution to many different (and often opposing) needs, and as a result is simultaneously awkward for experienced users while lacking sufficient guidance for new ones.

That said, I don't have any better ideas, and yours are far short of being fleshed out enough to really even discuss much less act on.

So instead of trying to discuss them, I'm going to point you here: [Can we talk about the voting culture here on Meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617)

Comment: Tempted to flag as NAA ;)