# Shop system. Reputation points buyable for real currency

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

Make a shop system, in which we can buy reputation packs for real money. There should be daily limit on how much of reputation we can buy a day. There could be also other features to buy. Here are my proposals:

- Golden frame around questions and answers.
- Bigger font of our comments or ability to move them up.
- One-time-use moderator actions for buy - except ban.
- Ability to remove some reputation from user. The more reputation for remove, the bigger cost.
- Ability to instantly show to other user big window with message on 
  top of his screen.

Comment: Will there be the possibility to activate the `<blink>` tag? I'm not even discussing this without a `<blink>` tag.

Comment: Only if I can also sell my rep!

Comment: so wait, you want to have an ability to increase/decrease someone's reputation but somehow that's different from purchasing upvotes... ? it's only different because it lets you purchase upvotes **and** downvotes. but then we enter the really grimy part: how much reputation does a single `1 USD` buy compared to `1 GBP` compared to `1 AUD` compared to `1 CHY`

Comment: @Shark: The difference is probably that you wouldn't be buying votes, just rep. (like that's a significant difference)

Comment: @Cerbrus there actually is: the tag badges are based on votes and not on rep.

Comment: @Cerbrus i made a update while your comment was coming in; please revise and reconsider :)

Comment: Hey! That man worked very hard for his reputation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear because it doesn't include any justification or detail about the feature you are requesting.  Please read about [how to write a good feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617).

Comment: I'll say this for your idea: turning SO into a PvP MMPORG might be better than turning it into a social network.

Comment: The question isn't _unclear_, but just asking for an absurd feature request, that already was declined. Should be left here for _taring and feathering_.

Comment: The question is *perfectly* clear.  There's no reason to close it for lack of clarity just so it stands a better chance of being deleted.  It was *already* undeleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Makoto If it should be deleted is arguable IMHO. As mentioned it should be left as the body hung at the pole.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ:  I see no reason to *delete* it, either.  At a bare minimum, it will send a strong message to anyone else who suggests something similar just how the community feels about it.

Comment: Well, if you are concerned about reputation, then you should not ask extremely broad questions like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625790/few-questions-about-visual-studio-2015-git

Comment: This is quite a good troll post "big window with message on top of his screen"

Answer (score 164):

No, that's an absurd idea and so far removed from acceptable discourse that I feel a little bad for even responding to it, but here goes anyway:

> Golden frame around questions and answers.

Probably the most harmless suggestion of the bunch, but still very contrary to what Stack Overflow is about. We don't care about who posted it, just about the content. A needless UI clutter golden frame would if anything make people hate your question more.

> Bigger font of our comments or ability to move them up.

We already have a process for this, it's called comment upvotes. There is no discernible reason why you should be able to do that with money and if you could, that would just mean that bored people with money can clutter the comments section more. Comments are also subject to deletion at any point, so that'd be another can of worms. Good comments already rise to the top, so no new feature is needed here.

> One-time-use moderator actions for buy - except ban.

That's absurd. Stack Overflow wants people to perform moderation actions - it's why we have them already. But we want only people who we can trust to not misuse the privileges to do that. And that you have money to pay for it is not in any way indicative that we should trust you with it. Also: Moderation actions can get reversed, easily. Questions can be reopened, posts can be undeleted, edits can be reversed. That'd be another can of worms.

> Ability to remove some reputation from user. The more reputation for
>   remove, the bigger cost.

We have the downvote, but it's not targeted at users. We don't target users here, we vote and assign reputation only based on content. Not only would this allow people with money to just take rep from others for no reason, it would also break the "focus on the content, not the poster" paradigm that's so central to Stack Overflow as a community.

> Ability to instantly show to other user big window with message on top
>   of his screen.

The success of this community hinges on the fact that we get experts (whose time is very valuable) to donate their work and time for free here by giving answers. Guess who is likely to stop doing that if we allow anyone with a few bucks to annoy them with big messages. Right. That's absurd.

**tl;dr: This entire proposal is absurd and completely outlandish and that you suggest it betrays a lack of understanding of the principles this site is based on.**

Comment: Hey if computer games can be pay-to-win, then SO and all its gamification can be brought to the point where you pay-to-be-reputable ;)

Comment: Now look just how well Stack Exchange, Inc. has listened to this philosophy. *"…we don't care about who posted it…"* *"…a needless UI golden frame…"* **cough cough Collectives cough Recognized User Badges cough**

Answer (score 47):

Simply and strictly

## NO!

Reputation can't be bought.

Reputation comes from your positive contributions to this site, where these are

- accepted edits on posts
- well achieved questions or answers

## Period!

And these are judged from peer users upon what's left by you regarding contents.

Money is irrelevant here, and that's good so, because such would just completely distort any community judgment upon such content.

---

- If you want better answers, post better questions
- If you want upvotes write better posts
- If you want to promote questions apply a bounty
- If you want any moderation privileges, gain reputation, so that we can trust you for some deeper understanding how things work here (that's something you can't get bought in).

Comment: No freehand circles -1

Comment: Oh come on. If you're gonna answer a troll question can you at least post a troll answer? You're being way too serious... :)

Comment: @rightfold Freehand _golden border circles_ or what??

Comment: @Mysticial I'm always serious, even if I'm going to be sarcastic.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm not _trolling_ ever, is that a _real problem_ here?

Answer (score 16):

No, just no.

Having a high reputation means that you have posted good quality answers and questions. "Buying" reputation just defeats the purpose of this site. And, you mentioned gaining moderator privileges? People are going to end up abusing them, as moderator privileges are meant for trusted users on the site.

The bottom line is, if you want reputation, you need to earn it.

Answer (score 1):

Just giving more reasons why this would not work, as it pertains to trust-based systems in general.

- Reputation is self-explanatory: those who have it are reputable (i.e. trustworthy), and those who do not are not. Allowing this would essentially be allowing anyone with 25 thousand reputation worth of money to (1) access analytics and (2) have access to all achievable moderation tools for life (or as long as they make it before getting banned), as long as they do not post, due to the absence of methods for the community to downvote a user without them creating content.
- Users with enough money would be able to remove other users' reputation, effectively censoring them.
- Users could deface posts and delete posts on meta addressing their behavior.