# Can we please answer questions about NullPointerException before closing them as duplicates of /q/218384?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Occasionally, users ask questions about solving [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)s in Java programs and get their questions closed as duplicates of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) before someone gives an answer.

We should stop doing this.

`NullPointerException` is a bug that can be solved much easier with a direct heads-up like *"You forgot to initialize `foo` before calling `foo.bar()`"*, and this heads-up should be given as an answer instead of [a series of comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0f8O.png).

Comment: Why? The duplicate tells anyone who reads it exactly what to do to resolve their issue. We don't need more answers explaining the same thing. In addition, if the OPs read the duplicate they might learn enough to solve the problem on their own next time it happens (and it will happen again). Telling the OP how to fix his problem is just spoon feeding and doesn't encourage learning. Teach a man to fish etc...

Comment: oh so you're all for MORE copy pasta coders who can't understand basic programming concepts?

Comment: This post got downvoted to the point of devolving from a disliked proposal to a source of shame (what other feeling can a net score of -33 give?). I have to delete it.

Comment: Here's a vote to delete your shame.

Comment: On a different perspective, this can be a signpost similar to [the pay-to-be-reputable proposal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326492/shop-system-reputation-points-buyable-for-real-currency)...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Stack Overflow is not a personal help desk for customized support to solve your specific problems and hold your hand through your debugging/troubleshooting.  It is designed to be a research tool.

If someone is pointed to that question via a duplicate flag, they either should be able to figure out what the problem is (assuming they know how to use the IDE), or they should have enough info to ask a question about the actual problem that is causing the NullPointerException.

In short, we shouldn't prevent closure just because someone doesn't know how to debug their program.

Comment: On the gripping hand, any post with +10 duplicates should start prunnin duplicates.

Comment: While I appreciate the irony of this question, its circumstances are indeed unfortunate.