# Is this newbie question about a segmentation fault in C not acceptable for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

I am a C newbie, and have recently asked the following question:

[Why am I getting a segmentation fault on a limit less than 169?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805162/c-newbie-here-why-am-i-getting-a-segmentation-fault-on-a-limit-less-than-169)

However, my question has received a downvote. Should I take this to mean that the question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow? Is there something wrong with the question that I should fix, or do I need to delete it?

Comment: As you will soon see, the policy is: _"Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Comment: Note: This includes you had inspected your code with the debugger. Just dumping all the code and expect we should do this for you, isn't well appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @πάνταῥεῖ for the insight. I debugged this quite a bit and I wasn't just expecting somebody to do my work for me as I don't think I have anything to gain from that. I'm curious to learn and I couldn't explain the behavior on my own. It seems like I did a poor job of asking the question but that was certainly not my intention.

Comment: It is important to note that, in the Stack Overflow mindset, there is *no such thing* as "a newbie question" - only one that should have been answered by doing appropriate [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), or one where the asker has already seen an answer elsewhere and needs help understanding it (which is off topic; we don't know *why* the asker can't understand it, and chances are that personalized tutorial is needed instead). We *do not care* about OP's level of experience with the language; we care about OP following the steps to ask a question properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A single downvote is really nothing to freak out about. If you start attracting several downvotes on the same question, then you will have a reason to take stock.

There are many reasons someone could have downvoted your question. It looks to me like you have posted a whole lot of code for something that is actually a rather simple issue, and would therefore be easy to demonstrate with [only a few lines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That's a common reason for a downvote. So is someone feeling that your question is "not interesting" and "not likely to be helpful for others in the future". Voting is how we rank content. Although your question is useful to you, and acceptable for the format, is it not likely to be widely considered interesting and helpful by other followers of the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag.

There is also a fairly high expectation that you will conduct some research and try to solve a problem yourself. [Being completely unaware of the existence of "undefined behavior"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805162/c-newbie-here-why-am-i-getting-a-segmentation-fault-on-a-limit-less-than-169#comment64979465_38805243) is a sign that you probably didn't do enough [background research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault) before posting the question. If nothing else, this should have been mentioned by your C book. If it doesn't talk about undefined behavior anywhere, you should [consider getting a different book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Note that it is rarely useful for the first line of a question to be an announcement that you are a "newbie". If that is not obvious from the question itself, we don't really need to know. It is "chatty" and will probably just cast the rest of the content in a less flattering light than if it stood on its own merit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looking back, some of the points you make seem reasonable. At the time I asked the question thought I couldn't have thought of them. I am not completely unaware of undefined behavior. The nature of its definition makes it difficult to accept that certain things are a result of undefined behavior. I expect this will become easier with experience.

Comment: I guess this question is not acceptable on StackOverflow meta. Luckily it's the end of the stack.

Comment: @MariusPop Well, downvotes on meta don't necessarily mean that a question or an answer is bad. Consider [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328042/6304349) for example - it has a ton of downvotes not because it sucks but because users disagree with what it proposes.

Comment: Downvotes are very different on Meta, @Marius. In particular, they often reflect *disagreement*, and that sometimes gets muddied into downvoting out of a general distaste for/dislike towards the question. I suspect that's what happened here. -3 is not really a bad score as far as things go on Meta. Reasonable questions have been known to fare much worse. The redeeming factor is that there is no reputation on Meta, so it doesn't matter how many downvotes you get. (As a side note, I'm not sure the concept of UB ever becomes more reasonable. It's always a bit absurd. But you get used to it.)