# Why are there questions in the triage queue that have a pending edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

Why are there questions in the triage queue that have a pending edit?

Or in other words: why should I judge questions that are presented to me in a state that is most probably not their future state?

Is this even intended like this or is it a bug?

Comment: Unfortunately, as Triage is a Stack Overflow-only feature, we have to mark this as "site-specific" here. It's worth noting, however, that the same problem [also exists with the Close Votes and Reopen Votes queue](/questions/328043/show-that-theres-a-pending-suggested-edit-in-the-close-reopen-votes-review-queu), and I've posted an argument as to why pending edits should be shown in reviews there.

Comment: Understanding the triage queue requires understanding Dilbert cartoons first.

Comment: @hans-passant Nice one! :D

Comment: @gparyani Your link keeps redirecting to this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328042/can-we-please-answer-questions-about-nullpointerexception-before-closing-them-as/328043#328043

Comment: @BSMP It was a relative URL link. I posted that comment before the question was migrated, and it seems the migration has broken the link. Modify the link URL to meta.stackexchange.com to see what I'm referring to.

Comment: @BSMP MSE bug filed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333880/relative-url-links-break-when-a-question-is-migrated

Comment: @gparyani except that it has been downgraded to a feature request now and we all know how far those go nowadays. I can't say I really agree with the tag change...