# The value of an edit timer?

Tags: feature-request, edits

I noticed that a decently formatted question was edited by another user within 40 seconds of being posted. Is there value in having other users edit submissions so quickly?

[image]

Would it be valuable to grant the OP some type of grace period? A minute, 90 seconds? It essentially gives the OP a small window of time to correct their post, instead of being immediately inundated with unsolicited edits that could potentially alter the question context.

Comment: OP has unlimited time before he even posts the question. Also I don't see what is wrong if someone improves a post, if it is within a minute OP asks the question or after a day.

Comment: If you don't like *"unsolicited edits"*, you probably shouldn't use a collaboratively-edited site. If edits alter the context, *whenever they're posted*, there are already tools for dealing with that. Also nobody is required to post before they've actually finished writing it.

Comment: Given that down votes on new questions can come in at an alarming rate, it is important to quickly fix questions that seem to have value. If not they might be lost forever. I don't see much problem in it.

Comment: @Rizier Did you read that link? http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta This is not tagged as a feature request. "Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

Comment: @niton That link isn't the end-all, be-all of voting classification on meta.

Comment: @niton That's what the help center says, as a guideline, but in reality a lot of people do vote on their agreement with the premise of the post, regardless of tag. This post suggests a time limit before the first non-OP edit, and people disagree with that idea. Hence, they downvote.

Comment: @niton This question is proposing a feature.  That it was mis-tagged doesn't change that (although that's easily fixed).  Also, that page isn't proscriptive, it's descriptive.  When a quesiton contains a proposal people often vote, at least in part, based on their agreement with the proposal.  That page is attempting to explain that (although I feel it does a very poor job of it), not describe how people are *obligated* to vote.  If you'd like a *good* explanation of this behavior, see [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1159478).

Comment: @Lux coming from outside this discussion.... it doesn't feel like the other users are the ones who are getting aggravated, really. Curt a bit? Maybe  Anyway... editing is an important part of the website, and is a good way to provide some help to a question if you still can't answer it. "unsollicited" edits.... don't really work here. When you post your post on stack, you ARE inviting edits.... if you don't want edits... then this site might not be build on the model you are looking for :/

Comment: @Patrice Oh, I know. The content of the edit wasn't the issue, just the timing.

Comment: @lux Well the "unsollicited" in your question makes it sound a bit different :P. I kinda focused on that. In any case.... why is the timing an actual issue? Because it comes quick, before the poster can correct it himself? I mean I kinda get what you're coming from, but... as someone who doesn't really ask questions here, whenever I do I proofread them like CRAZY, so maybe I don't see it the same way as you?

Comment: @Patrice `Because it comes quick, before the poster can correct it himself?` Yes. I think in the 40 seconds the issue was posted, the OP would have corrected or reformatted appropriately.

Comment: @lux but.... IF 40 seconds is enough time for the user to see and correct his mistake... then it SHOULD have been caught in the proofreading. We are supposed to "pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". If I am to send an email to the busiest guy in my office I'd re-read it enough I know I am not letting mistakes slip. I just feel like allowing that grace-period KINDA goes against how we ASK people to do questions... now... I understand that in reality, very little people actually do it, so maybe that's why your request makes sense?

Comment: @Patrice I get it. People have infinite time to create posts, and in that time they are infallible. Let's all move on.

Comment: @lux it's NOT a matter of being infallible. I understand mistakes, I understand everyone makes some. The problem I have with your proposal is that if it was so easy as to only need 1 minute to catch, then the OP didn't properly proofread what he posted. If it takes 10-15 minutes to realize, that's another thing, not something a rapid proofread would help with. If you don't want "silly" edits, then proofread more and more until you won't get them... I just feel it's contradictory to say it's a quick fix, then to say someone lets it through (the assumption being a GOOD, thorough proofread here).

Comment: @lux Nobody ever said that people are infallable or cannot have any mistakes in posts that they post here.  The point is that, before posting their question, they should make it *as good as they are capable of making it*.  So, given that we know the question is as good as the author is capable of making it, giving them more time to edit it wouldn't help.  Any mistakes in the post (because having some is quite understandable) should be assumed to be something they weren't capable of fixing on their own, so the community should edit the post.

Comment: *instead of being immediately inundated with unsolicited edits that could potentially alter the question context* - Why do you think this is likely if the edit in your post was actually OK?

Answer (score 17):

> Is there value in having other users edit submissions so quickly?

There's just as much value as there is in performing the same edit at any other point in time.  I guess the earlier edit is more valuable in the sense that more people will see the improved question, post edit.

Of course, if the edit doesn't improve the post, then that's another matter, and has nothing to do with when it's applied.

> Would it be valuable to grant the OP some type of grace period?

They have as much time as they could ever want before they submit their post.  If they're not done writing the post, they need only refrain from posting it until they *are* ready.

> edits that could potentially alter the question context.

If an edit changes what a question is asking then that's an inappropriate edit, and should be rolled back, regardless of whether it's applied 30 seconds after the post is posted or 2 days after the post is posted.

Answer (score 9):

The [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40184130/2) you refer to isn't a bad edit. It improves formatting and makes the snippet easy to copy/paste into another window. Additionally, the user making the edit has *long* surpassed the [privilege requirements to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) without peer review. The OP was not inconvenienced with the need to approve or deny this edit.

The OP does not need a grace period. They have all the time they need to post a question, edit it, and ensure that it's presented correctly. When the OP posts a question to [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), a tag with 1.2M posts as of this answer, a well presented question is the difference between someone spending a few minutes to answer and someone ignoring (or downvoting, or close voting) the question. This edit, and large majority of other edits, help to improve the chances a user will get their question answered.