# Why is Stack Exchange so bent on not have a question that discusses things?

Tags: discussion, scope

Why does Stack Exchange penalize people that ask questions that call for a discussion. Isn't that what gaining knowledge is about? And why do people get so bent out of shape for that?

I believed the main point of any site such as Stack Exchange was to discuss things in a constructive manner and not just be a question answer site.

Before people point me to the official rules of asking questions on Stack Exchange, I am asking why those rules are there in the first place.

Comment: But *why* do you choose to believe so, if the very first paragraph of the [tour] literally starts with "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site ..."?

Comment: ... Here is a more practical answer. One cannot put a definitve answer to such open discussions, and voting up and down would merely mean "I agree/I disagree" (voting on Meta [works that way](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) though - but it is one place where we discuss stuff). If you stick to *facts*, those can be wrong or right. That said, can you include an example of a such a discussion, so we can explain why it cannot be answered on an SE site? (Maybe it could.)

Comment: Often times, if something is too opinion-based on SO Main, you can ask in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). (Unlocked at 20 rep)

Comment: @RadLexus Voting up and down reflects an opinion regardless  ("I believe this answer is useful"), and it's not like there's a definitive answer to every question in a question-answer format. The bigger difference is that answers themselves do not invite followup discussion to nearly the same extent.

Comment: And disagreement with the question's premise.

Comment: @Rad The meta help link contradicts the community behaviour, except for feature-requests. It is confusing since it indicates the voters are wrong. You could offer this instead. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 35):

> I believed the main point of any site such as stackexchange was to discuss things in a constructive manner and not just be a question answer site.

Then, you're simply wrong.

There are many places you can go online to have open-ended discussions, **this isn't one of them**. We are "just" a Q/A site. Cut-and-dry, no opinions or open-ended discussion, just questions and (ideally) reference-quality answers.

> Before people point me to the official rules of asking questions on Stack Exchange, I am asking why those rules are there in the first place.

Because, again, there are lots of places where you can go to have discussions. Those places usually aren't very useful when you have a specific problem that you suspect other people have had in the past.

Comment: FWIW there's some sites like Code Review, Software Engineering and The Workplace that deal with questions where there's often not *"the only right"* answer. This requires a different voting and answering culture, but it works in this system to an extent. But even there people seem to like to complain that there isn't enough discussion ...

Comment: @Vogel612 Software Engineering has dedicated meta guidance: [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Answer (score 16):

(I will restrict the scope of this answer to Stack Overflow.)

> Why does stackexchange very heavily penalize people that ask questions that call for a discussion. Isn't that what gaining knowledge is about ?

Because Stack Overflow is not simply about gaining knowledge. It is about gaining knowledge through questions and answers, and gathering this knowledge in a way that makes it immediately useful for as many people as possible. The rules about which kinds of question are acceptable follow from that goal. There are plenty of legitimate ways of gaining and gathering knowledge according to different priorities, but Stack Overflow isn't meant to encompass all of them. You don't criticise a poet for not writing in paragraphs of appropriate length, even though both poetry and prose are forms of writing. In a similar vein, you shouldn't expect to find free-form discussion in Stack Overflow merely because that also may be a form of gaining knowledge.