# Asking a quiz question - Is it OK?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I just posted a quiz question, and it got closed. I have a hard time to understand why because:

1. [We agree that we can ask question that we already know the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463)
2. For me Stack Overflow is a place to learn. Every time someone comes to visit the site, either to read or to ask something, it's because he/she wants to learn something. And a quiz can help people to learn.
3. A quiz is in the format: question/answer which fits the Stack Overflow question/answer format
4. I saw plenty of quiz in the past while surfing the site.

Here is the question: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468279/async-quiz-what-will-this-print*

Answer (score 13):

You did not ask the question the smart way. If you had posted a minimal and complete example of the code, showed the output that it produced, and then asked for an explanation of *why* it was producing that output, your question would likely not have been closed.

Mind you, it would not have been a *good* question, and is therefore likely to have received downvotes, but it would have been on topic.

Please do not ask "quiz" questions that are obviously copy-pasted from a quiz. I do not believe that you have seen other examples of these on the site, and if you have, it's only because we missed closing them.

> And a quiz can help people to learn.

No, quizzes don't help anyone to learn anything. They *test* someone's knowledge (in theory) to see if they *have already* learned something. No one who answers questions here is interested in taking a quiz.

Comment: You mean that solving problem has never helped you to learn!? I'm sorry then...

Comment: There is no problem to be solved in the question you asked. Not the educational kind, at least. You either know the answer or you don't. That's the opposite of learning. "Why is the sky blue?" Did you learn anything?

Comment: What if I say yes? http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/blue-sky/en/. A quiz force you to search for the answer.

Comment: If you were able to find the answer, why did you ask the question in the first place? This makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: "You mean that solving problem has never helped you to learn!?" -- Certainly it has; however, [Stack Overflow does not encompass all possible ways of learning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337493/2751851).

Answer (score 8):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

(emphasis mine)

A quiz question is not a practical problem. We have dedicated site for [programming puzzles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) but this question won't fit there, either.

> I saw plenty of quiz in the past while surfing the site.

If you see one of those, you should flag to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: Well, *certain* quiz questions might also happen to be practical problems.  Many won't, this particular one isn't.