# How to prevent a poorly worded question that I'm working to answer from being deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A user asked a legitimate (but poorly worded) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593399/having-trouble-with-system-valuetuple-in-c-sharp/49593508), which I took the time to research and answer.

[image: Screenshot of deleted question]

After answering, I intended to edit the question to fit the SO question guidelines. However, the question was deleted by the community before I could do so.

It appeared that the question was deleted immediately after the OP accepted my answer. From my perspective, my answer was evidence that the question was active, and so the question should have been given a chance to be corrected.

Users with more rep than myself surely have the ability to edit deleted questions and revive them, but I don't, and had the community not been so aggressive in deleting this (answered and active) question, it could have provided value to the community after a quick edit.

**Before my question is started to be seen as a rant:** what could I have done differently in this situation to keep the question on SO and/or show that my answer provided value?

If I were to answer this question myself, I would say to edit the poorly worded question first before answering, so that it has less time to be flagged. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Just ask the question yourself if it is interesting and salvageable.  And answer it.

Comment: I know that users incidentally answer their own questions sometimes, but it seems odd and perhaps against the spirit of SO to post questions that one already knows the answer to. If to do so wasn't frowned upon, then tech bloggers would make their own "blog posts" on SO, wouldn't they? And GitHub users would write questions specific to the repos that they've created. Seems like a conflict of interest.

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). - Yes, it is allowed and encouraged.

Comment: It's exactly in the spirit. SO is designed to _help future visitors_.

Comment: I was one of those who voted to close this question.  You should have edited the question first to bring it on topic which you already realized in hindsight, that would have at least slowed the vote to close. When I came across the question it was not in standing with the guidelines of the site. the OP had more than enough time to edit it into shape.

Comment: About "blog posts"... if it's sufficiently interesting and can help future visitors, it can be asked&answered on SO. But most of the time it's a dupe, so no.

Comment: About Github repo... our rules contain "Questions must be self-contained", pointing to an external repo without including any code inside is delete-worthy.

Comment: @eclecticist at this stage I would suggest you go with the self answer route and in future first try to get the OP to fix their question if it is off topic. You souldn't really be the one to fix it, but if you see room for improving the post then you are free to do so at your own expense.

Comment: @eclecticist Remember that questions should be self-contained. If you ask "What does A do at the link my.toolbox.com" then, no. Otherwise, make sure that your question can be _helpful to future users_.

Comment: @user202729 Of course, makes sense. Thank you all for the great advice.

Comment: It shouldn't have been deleted so quickly. That should be reserved for things that are utterly unsalvageable even if the advice in the close notice was taken on board. If you  get the impression a question may be deleted then obviously prioritise fixing it over providing an answer though but I'm not sure you will see delete votes at 6 rep.

Comment: What was the time elapsed between question closure and deletion? I'm on mobile so can't hover over to get the exact time stamps. I can just see it was less than 1 HR.

Comment: @MartinSmith It was put on hold 40 minutes after being posted and deleted after an additional 16 minutes.

Comment: Thanks - no way it should have been deleted in those time scales IMO

Comment: I had a similar problem yesterday with a question that was marked as a duplicate of an existing question. It was a duplicate, but the existing answer was 8 years out of date, so marking it as a duplicate was really unhelpful.

Comment: @MartinSmith deleting an hour after it was posted seems more than enough. I frequently check low score open questions and you'll be surprised how quickly do _sensible_ askers correct their questions after getting a bunch of downvotes. It regularly happens in a matter of few minutes. If asker didn't bother to improve in about an hour it is most likely that they won't do it at all

Comment: @gnat asked Q on that specific issue https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365467/73226

Comment: If you see gold in a lump of rock, ***[EDIT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261574/603977)*** so that everyone else can see it too.

Comment: This has been a useful conversation, but does anyone think that it might be time to take the guys picture down from the top of this post. The conversation can continue without the profile pic.

Comment: @dcary Definitely; the username shouldn't have been there to begin with, IMO. Its quite a small effort to cut it out of the screenshot before uploading.

Comment: Be careful about self answered questions, while they are "encouraged" officially by the site, it can be rather difficult to make a successful Q/A pair and I think the commenters are glossing over that. 1) the question must have somewhat broad appeal, or it will get automatically deleted if it fails to get any votes, and 2) your question must show all of the usual signs of quality (research effort, etc.). It might feel like you're repeating yourself, but putting these details only in the answer is generally not sufficient and will probably result in downvotes.

Comment: Also... for those of you guys who are saying the OP should have edited the question, note that the OP has 6 rep, so that would have been a *suggested edit* -- what would have happened if it took more than an hour (likely, from my experience) to approve the edit? Also there's site guidelines against "turd polishing" which some users might think this question would fall under.

Comment: @jrh It's pretty rare for a suggested edit to take more than an hour.  The guidance against turd polishing is that you shouldn't be editing a question that is *still a bad question* after your edits.  Turning a bad question into a good one is the *ideal* case for edits (although most people fail to actually accomplish that).

Comment: "had the community not been so aggressive in..." - This is how most of my concerns with SO start :(

Comment: @Gimby Image/username/advertisement have been removed.

Comment: @jrh It's true that a suggested edit takes longer than an immediate one but it's still the best way to prevent the question from getting deleted. The only other thing to do is ask the OP to fix it themselves.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

IMHO, Poorly worded doesn't even begin to describe this question.
Questions like this should not be encouraged by answering them.
I mean, take a look at the screenshot you took, and imagine having no prior knowledge about this question. Can you even guess what the problem, or the error message is?

Questions should be self contained - meaning they should have a clear definition of the problem, if it's a question about code they should contain the minimal version of the code needed to replicate the problem ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and the error message, if there is one, should be included in the message body as text, not as an image.
They should also show the OP's (Original Poster) effort of solving the problem prior to asking the community's help.

A question like that should be [flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as very low quality (which you can do once you have at least 15 reputation points). Once you have 50 reputation points, You should also leave a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on the question detailing the problems in the question to the OP.

I admit this is more a rule of thumb, and I've answered a few low quality questions myself, but it usually turns out to be a mistake. Some community members think they should downvote even good answers if the question is poor (I think they shouldn't - because I think that it is possible to post good, helpful answers to some law quality questions), and of course, there's always a chance that the question will be deleted either by a moderator or by the community itself (once you have [10,000 reputation points you can vote to delete/undelete questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools); at [20,000 reputation you get expanded delete-/undelete-vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).

So, to summarize: Answering such questions is a mistake. If you think the only thing wrong with a question is the way it's worded, **you should first edit it**, and only then answer. In this case, you might want to post a self answered question as noted by some of the comments to your question.

To address the conversation I've had with Servy in the comments - here is a detailed explanation of good, helpful answers to low quality questions:

I answer a lot of SQL questions, mainly SQL-Server related. 
Most of the questions I see being asked lacks a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A lot of people are posting their sample data in the form of a visual table, thinking (rightfully) that it's easy to read and understand.
However, when you want to answer such questions, you can't just copy and paste the sample data, and then use it as is to check your answer before posting.
What I do in cases like this, where the question itself is good but the sample data is malformed, (and as I wrote, it's very common) is to copy the sample data from the question, refactor it into [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) and [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language), and incorporate that into my answer. So most of my SQL answers are built like this:

Explanation
Sample Data
SQL Statement
Results
Link to online demo

When I do post sample data, I start with the following sentence:

> First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

Most of the time, especially if I actually helped to solve the problem, I get a response from the OP saying they will post sample data as DDL+DML in their next questions.

So this is an example of how a good answer can be helpful not only to future readers having similar problems, but to future questions posted by the same person.

Comment: So you think that answering questions like these is harmful, and that it shouldn't be done, but you think those answers should be upvoted, even though they're not helpful, and not downvoted, even though they aren't helpful.  You are expected to vote based on the usefulness of the post.  A question being bad doesn't automatically make the answer useful (or prevent it from being unhelpful).

Comment: @Servy Not quite; I think that even if the question is badly formed, it can still have good answers. If a question is so badly formed it should be completely re-written, such as the question in this case, then it's not worth answering before it's edited to fit at least minimal standard.

Comment: So you think that the question shouldn't be answered, because answering it wouldn't be helpful, but you think that answers to it are helpful, even though you've only ever stated reasons for why they're not helpful and provided no reasons for why they're helpful.  If you think that answering such questions is useful, why say that it's not useful, and why haven't you explained why it's useful to support your assertion that it's useful?

Comment: @Servy as I wrote, I think that this particular question should not have been answered. However, I don't think downvoting answers just because the question was very low quality is Ok either. Sometimes, badly formed questions can be edited into good, helpful questions. In such cases, I think it's better to first edit the question and then post an answer. Had the question starting this post been edited to fit the "standard", (include the code and error message), it might have prove useful for some future readers. some question are salvageable, that's kinda my entire point.

Comment: You should be voting based on how useful an answer *actually is*, not how useful a post *might become* after a bunch of heroic edits (that in practice almost never actually happen) get made.  If the question gets edited into a good question, and as a result the answer has become useful *then* it would merit an upvote.  But until that happens, the answer *isn't* useful, and its vote should reflect it.  If you are posting an answer and want it to be upvoted, and not downvoted, you should ensure that it's helpful *right away*, rather than hoping it becomes useful in the future.

Comment: @Servy I agree, that's why I wrote  in the last paragraph of my answer "If you think the only thing wrong with a question is the way it's worded, you should first edit it, and only then answer."

Comment: So then why also say that people should vote contrary to a post's actual usefulness whenever there is a bad question?  Telling people to not post bad answers is good advice.  Telling people to falsely indicate the actual value of answers posted is *not* good advice.  We want people providing *accurate* feedback on how useful a given answer actually is, in addition to encouraging people to post good answers.  (Providing accurate feedback is in fact *how* we encourage people to post good answers.)

Comment: @Servy because I think that an answer might be good and helpful even if the question is not that good. I've seen good answers getting downvoted just because the question was "too basic" - not even badly formed, just an RTM question. I think that's wrong.

Comment: So then why are you telling people not to answer such questions as such answers wouldn't be useful?  If you think that answering these questions is helpful, then explain why it's helpful to answer bad questions like these.  If you actually think that answers to these questions have a good shot at being useful, then by all means, explain as much.  But as it stands you're telling people that the answers *aren't* useful, but that they should vote as if they were useful even though they aren't.

Comment: @Servy I feel like we are going in circles here. I think I've explained my position in our conversation. Of course, that's my opinion and you are free to disagree with me. In fact, there is even a badge for posting good answers to poor questions - called [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) - awarded for providing a +20 answer to a -5 question...

Comment: But you haven't explained your position.  You've just stated repeatedly that answers to bad questions aren't useful, and that you shouldn't downvote those answers even though they aren't useful.   You haven't explained why posting these types of answers is actually useful, or why the explanation you've given for why they *aren't* useful doesn't apply.

Comment: @Servy I think that even bad questions can have good answers. I understand you think that's wrong. I have explained my position repeatedly. I don't think I can explain it better and frankly, I'm not interested in doing that any more.

Comment: Like I said, if you think that it's useful to answer bad questions, then that's fine, but you should edit your answer to explain why editing questions like these is helpful, because right now your answer is explaining why answering questions like these *isn't* useful.  Currently you *haven't* explained why answering questions like these is useful, you've just *stated*, without reasoning, that such answers are useful, again and again, despite your answer only ever explaining why they aren't useful.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to disagree about down voting an answer to a bad question.  You **should** down vote those answers.  They are not useful because they are detrimental to the site by feeding help vampires.  They encourage questioners to not improve.

Comment: No need to flag as low quality. Just flag for closure with an appropriate reason. (Lacks MVCE and Unclear both work.)

Comment: @Servy I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: @zero298 I don't think all very low quality questions are from help vampires. Questions like that should not get answers at all. However, some low quality questions are legitimate questions. Not every OP goes to the tour and reads how-to-ask before posting their first question.  There are many variables to consider - such as - Is this a question from someone that's new here? If not, is it from someone that only asks questions, all poor quality (a sign of the help vampire), and so on.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sure, if someone posts a good question that just has a little bit of bad formatting that's trivially fixed that may not necessarily make an answer not useful, particularly if the answerer edits the question first to fix that problem.  Why you'd decide to take the time to fix the question's improper formatting *and then not edit the fix into the question* is beyond me, but the point remains that such a minor problem with the question just don't inhibit the ability of it to be answered or for that answer to be useful.  None of that is true for a question with *significant* problems.

Comment: When a question is bad enough that it actually merits closure or deletion, because it's problems are *that* severe, it's a completely different matter.  In such cases the problems with the question *by definition* impact how useful an answer can possibly be.  So sure, a question with a typo or two, or some improper formatting can still have a useful answer, but this whole thing is about quesitons with more serious problems that *can't* just be ignored.

Comment: @Servy hence the second sentence in my answer: "Questions like this should not be encouraged by answering them." All I'm saying is that there are levels of law quality answers, some of which it's perfectly fine to answer (again, IMHO), some are not.

Comment: @ZoharPeled A question with a minor problem that doesn't inhibit the ability of it to be answered with a very useful answer *isn't a low quality question*.  It's a *good* question that just has some *minor* problems that don't impact it's overall quality dramatically.

Comment: @Servy I post the sample data DDL+DML in the answer, because I think that the OP will have a better response to that then if I would simply edit that into the question. IMO, Once the problem is solved, people usually don't bother re-reading the question itself. In my experience, If I post the sample data correctly in the answer, then the OP is more likely to post the next questions with proper sample data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The *purpose* of questions on this site is for them to be found by all of the other people with that problem, so that they can then find the answer to that problem.  If you're only ever answering questions that nobody will ever read again then those questions, and your answers, are not actually useful.  This site is not a personal help desk that exists to provide a personalized answer to every person individually.  The site exists to create a canonical searchable reference source.

Comment: @Servy answer are seargable too... again, I think the only thing we might have a disagreement on is how bad a question needs to be in order to consider answering it as a bad thing.

Comment: @ZoharPeled The problem is that in your answer you *specifically* state that questions that you consider "low quality" both shouldn't be answered, don't have useful answers, but that those low quality answers that aren't useful should be upvoted, not downvoted.  This isn't about how bad a question needs to be to be low quality.  If a question is low enough quality that answering it isn't useful *then you should reflect that lack of usefulness in your votes*.

Comment: How severe the problems on the question need to be in order to prevent useful answers is indeed debatable, but the point is that when that point is reached, whenever that is, it means that the answers aren't useful, and your vote should reflect that.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Sometimes, just getting the question right is the only thing you need to get the answer. Read [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) for details. However, you do have a valid point - The primary goal of someone asking a question is to get a solution. The primary goal of someone giving an answer is to solve problems. If your solution can only help a single person, or if it can help a few, or even some more, what would you prefer?

Answer (score -22):

This seems absurd to me. Those timescales are far too short. This question wasn't even given a chance.

> @MartinSmith It was put on hold 40 minutes after being posted and
>   deleted after an additional 16 minutes. – eclecticist 23 hours ago

Yeah, it was a terrible question that took more work than should be necessary to figure out what has been asked. But apparently there was a real question there because someone was able to give it a good answer. That answer wasn't given a chance either. The whole thing was just thrown in the bin seemingly because people are so caught up with "it isn't following the rules!!" and want to be rid of it.

I've personally edited terrible questions into decent ones because I understood the topic. This is especially true in more niche topics like SSIS or something where if you don't really understand the topic the question almost looks like nonsense. I've also seen questions I could have answered closed.

It's this strange militant seeking out of anything that is even borderline unacceptable so that they can cast close and delete vote instead of actually putting any effort into improving the post. I've never really liked it and it's always made me feel like this is not a community I want to be a part of. So I generally stay on the sidelines and just ask/answer and try to ignore all of the strange politics that goes on.

I think it would have been much more useful to the OP to have their question edited into something useful and good by an experienced SO user. As it stands they learned nothing except that if they don't write the perfect question they aren't going to get any help here and no one is going to help them figure out what is the right way.

Sure, some questions are garbage. But 40 minutes to close and then 16 minutes to delete is not enough time to accurately assess anything but the most nonsense spam posts. It's always seemed to me that people here are far more interested in handing out punishment than help. I don't honestly understand why. It's a help site.

Comment: Yeah the votes make sense. SO is just a place to find bad questions and dunk on them. Not to actually help people learn. Ignore the fact that lots of these questions are from ESL people or that not everyone has the same capacity for language and expression despite not lacking in the ability to program or learn. I'll just go back to the shadows now...

Comment: _"*Borderline* unacceptable"_?! There's isn't even a question there. It's a screenshot of an error message. This isn't anywhere _close_ to the border. 40 minutes of time that this person forced others to waste because they couldn't be bothered to extend the basic courtesy of explaining their problem.

Comment: Then how did they manage to figure out the answer? I didn't see anything about them having a conversation in the comments. Sometimes an error message is enough. The error text could have been edited into the question.

Comment: We're missing the context that the OP of this question has. They knew the answer and could have edited the question. Less than an hour is not enough time. Why is it so important to get rid of this question so quickly?

Comment: But it's always seemed to me that people here are far more interested in handing out punishment than help. I don't honestly understand why. But I don't expect to change it either.

Comment: How long do we have to wait before closing/deleting questions like these? One hour? Two? A day? Are we supposed to start keeping huge lists of all these terrible questions to revisit again and again just to check if someone's fixed them yet?

Comment: I don't know. A day seems ok, even two. But less than one hour seems unreasonable to me. What harm is it doing by just existing? Why is it so important to have it gone so quickly? I don't understand this attitude at all. It's always made this place seem hostile to me but I'm in the minority so I've always just accepted it and not really participated. That's why I answered "No" to the survey question that asked if I felt like I was part of the SO community.

Comment: The fact remains the question had an answer. Proven by the fact that the OP of this question was the one who knew it. The question could have been improved and been helpful to the person who wrote it. Not just in the fact that it helped them with their programming problem. It could also have shown them what a good question looked like. That opportunity is gone now.

Comment: And I'm sure someone will come along and say "Oh these dumb people never learn! It's worthless to spend your time on it!" which is rather elitist but I get they've been burned by people on here. I have too. But just don't answer the question if you're burnt out on helping newbies. Don't be in such a rush to completely erase them from the site before they can get help. It might even take more than one question where they get help before they really get it. Some people aren't interested in learning but if you let them make you hate every new person then we may as well close registrations.

Comment: This is the wrong hill for you to pick to die on. A question like this has _never_, _ever_ been acceptable quality on this site. Yes, maybe it could be edited, and if so, it should be. But you know what? The asker could also show some respect for the site and the people from whom they want help. It's a two-way street.

Comment: Whatever dude. I saw this as an example of this terrible attitude that is so prevalent here.You are another good example of it. I don't actually like the SO community. It is pedantic and more interested in some vague idea of "purity" than helping people. I also saw this as an example of a missed opportunity to actually help someone. Everyone seems to be ignoring the fact that his "awful" question HAD AN ANSWER. That doesn't matter. You think the person who asked it doesn't deserve help because they aren't good enough for you. The question can still be answered as long as it doesn't help them.

Comment: Giving the question less than an hour to live is not reasonable. That doesn't give anyone a chance to improve anything. Did anyone try to help them? The OP of this question was but they didn't get the chance to. And according to everyone here that is just the way this site is supposed to work. Maybe we should test people before they can register for an account? Or a minimum education requirement? Maybe a degree in Computer Science. (Guess I'm gone.) If you expect everyone to come in here perfectly doing the right thing you're excluding a lot of people for reasons they can't control.

Comment: This answer reflects my initial thoughts. But Mike M.'s question of, "If we don't immediately flag garbage questions, how long do we wait?" is an excellent one. We don't have a system for tracking "currently-bad-but-maybe-somebody-will-edit" questions, and if we did, it would be a lot of overhead for the community. I think that voting to close questions that don't adhere to the guidelines upon seeing them is the easiest way to keep the quality of content on SO high, and to encourage posters of bad questions to post better questions.

Comment: I guess it is a point of contention between people who believe this site should help people and the people who think this site should be a perfect bit of documentation. Seems like they tried that...

Comment: *The question could have been improved...* You can't tell that by looking at it though. The OP makes reference to their code but then doesn't provide it. To anyone reviewing flags on it, the question looks unfixable by anyone other than the OP because only they can provide their code.

Comment: And actually Josh Caswell. Where did I say this question was "borderline"? I said it was terrible. But put words in my mouth. Your high rep score means more than anything else around here. This plebe will go back to being quiet.

Comment: @MikeD. I think you are among the few looking at other poster's rep in this discussion. It doesn't do your argument any favors.

Comment: And why do you need to keep a list of every bad question you've ever seen? Can you not go "Oh, this question has been open for less than an hour. I will give it a bit a longer and move on." I'm sure someone else will still vote to close it a day or even two days later if it is still unanswered and garbage.

Comment: I didn't have to look. I recognized the name. I'm sure I'm not the only one. But fair enough that it is an irrelevant point... that was a dumb thing to say.

Comment: @MikeD. I have no idea who you are. I couldn't care less about your rep. Have a bit less than you anyway. I still think your arguments do not hold, and that your ranting is a bit too much.

Comment: _"Where did I say this question was 'borderline'?"_ Your fourth paragraph starts "...seeking out of anything that is even borderline unacceptable..."

Comment: Everyone just seems to be in such a rush to delete questions and close them and I really don't get it. No one is asking you to manage a list of every bad question ever. But that doesn't mean it has to be done RIGHT NOW.

Comment: Which was more of a general statement. See the part where I said "It was a terrible question." Which I thought was rather clear.

Comment: @MikeD. If you want to participate in a site that doesn't have quality standards for posts, that's fine.  There are *lots* of places around the internet that don't bother with quality standards.  SO is in face one of *very* few sites that *does* have non-trivial quality standards for posts.  The users of this site feel that it is more beneficial to the programming community to have a site that has some quality standards.  If you prefer participating in a community that doesn't have quality standards, and that lets anyone post anything, then there are plenty of places that offer that.

Comment: I've always known my views have been the opposite of the general SO community. But I've never really liked it. This answer will get deleted like most every other time I interact here on meta.

Comment: Where did I say NO quality standards? Again, putting words in my mouth. But why are you in such a rush? Why does it have to be so quick?

Comment: The only answer anyone has given me is "Because then I have to keep a list of every bad question I see." Which is not at all a requirement.

Comment: @MikeD. You're saying that we should have quality standards and then refuse to enforce them, which is functionally the same as not having them.  So yes, you just said that we shouldn't *enforce* our quality standards, not that we shouldn't have them, but I don't see any meaningful difference between the two.

Comment: @MikeD. if this answre gets deleted, it is because it's a rant that **doesn't answer the question**. A variation of it could be posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365467/what-is-a-reasonable-length-of-time-to-give-for-a-poor-question-to-be-improved-b), for example. But here it's just a rant tangential to the question.

Comment: No, I meant I would probably delete it. And how does it not answer the question? I am specifically giving my opinion that the amount of time this question was given was not reasonable. That isn't off topic. It leads to a larger discussion of a problem I've always had with the way this place operates. Am I not allowed to mention that?

Comment: @MikeD. Sure, if you just refuse to close bad questions entirely then you're right, you don't need to have a list of bad questions.  But everyone else considers, "just don't close close-worthy questions at all" to be an even worse option than "keep a list of close-worthy questions to come back days later and close them".

Comment: @MikeD. Your answer *hasn't* been deleted, and has no delete votes, so let's try to hold off on rants about this meta answer being deleted until that actually happens, at which point, go nuts.

Comment: I didn't say NEVER close the questions. I said give them longer than an hour. FFS, you must be willfully misinterpreting me. If a question exists for longer than an hour can it never be deleted? No.

Comment: Sergey, are you not paying attention or is there just some lag in between our comments? I'm sure I'll delete this later. It isn't how the SO community feels. I won't want it hanging around on my profile. It isn't like it is going to make a difference.

Comment: @MikeD. So if you want people to wait a while then that means keeping a list and going back to it later.  You just said you weren't advocating people keep lists, and specifically said above that you expect people to just *not* vote to close questions that weren't old enough in your opinion.

Comment: No it doesn't. Why do YOU have to be the one to delete it? Won't other people come along later and come to the same conclusion? Isn't that the point of community moderation? That it isn't all on you.

Comment: @MikeD. And what about all of the problems caused between now and then?  And it takes a lot of people to close and delete a question, and votes expire over time, making it much harder for the proper moderation to happen if it doesn't happen when the question has most of its traffic.  and of course if *everyone* just decides to not bother and hope someone else handles it then *nothing gets done*.  The point of community moderation is that the community *actually moderates*, not that it refuses to moderate in the hopes that other people will moderate for them.

Comment: What problems? Is the "bad" question going around hitting other questions? Is it personally coming to your house and making you answer it?

Comment: I just don't see the point in deleting a question in under an hour. Clearly I must be wrong and that person did not deserve to get help from this website.

Comment: I just hate this obsession with purity of questions on here. I'd rather be inclusive and help people than exclude people. If you think nothing will be done by leaving the question there for even half a day then maybe something is wrong with the way questions get reviewed. But I still don't see the problem with giving a question a day or two to improve. I don't know the answer. I just don't think this was right. The community does not agree.

Comment: @MikeD. Yes, it is hurting other questions.  It's consuming the time of people, who'll end up looking at it instead of being able to spend that time on a useful question. Wasting a bunch of people's time hurts both the other questions on the site, and the individual users of the site.  It's far preferable for the first few people who see the question to properly mark it as needing improvement to be answered (or even unsalvageable) so that everyone else can just see that and not waste their time with it. Just because the question isn't committing physical violence doesn't mean it's not harmful.

Comment: How long would it take you to decide if you wanted to answer that question or not? I'm guessing you wouldn't have even clicked on the title except to cast a close vote. This is one of the reasons I do not ask many questions because it may not be "perfect" and I know how this community is. I do not see how people look at that situation and go "Yep, that's a good thing that people do not want to engage with our community."

Comment: @MikeD. Most questions *are* given a few days to improve, when a question is considered poor, but still salvageable.  It is when a question is considered so bad that there's no real reasonable path to improving it that it is deleted.

Comment: Well, in this case I think y'all were wrong. I think possibly in a lot of cases. *shrug*

Comment: @MikeD. Honestly no, I wouldn't have expected, from the title alone, that the question would be *that* bad.  There are questions that I know will be completely worthless from the title alone, but that isn't one of them for me.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the toil of clicking on a bad question and going "yeah this isn't for me." and moving on. But I only answer questions sporadically. So perhaps my perspective is different.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the toil of asking a coherent question, or getting feedback on the problems that my question has when it is problematic, rather than being expected to ask incoherent questions and refusing to allow others to inform me that it's problematic.

Comment: I guess you were born knowing how to ask a perfect question and write bug-free code too? Wow, that's amazing! You've never had to learn anything? That must make things very easy for you. No one ever gave you chance when you made a mistake when you first joined the site I'm sure. Ignore the fact that not everyone speaks english or has the same language capabilities that you do. Let's be ableist and classist (and probably a bit racist as a side-effect of socio-economic issues in that vein). Everyone needs to know everything before they post here or they don't deserve any help at all.

Comment: I didn't say *perfect*, I said *coherent*.  Asking amazing questions is quite hard.  It takes a lot of work.  Asking a question that's good enough that it doesn't need to be immediately deleted is a somewhat lower bar.  And of course when I made mistakes I didn't expect people to just ignore them and pretend they didn't exist.  When they do that, I can't fix the problem.  By properly moderating the bad questions people are given the feedback on the problems with their posts, that then can then use to fix them (or at least not make the same mistakes in the future).

Comment: I disagree with your entire philosophy. If you don't see how it is more reasonable for you to click a question and move on than for someone who is knew to know everything and do nothing wrong. Which has to be the case if you're advocating nuking questions in under an hour. But I think this was all decided years ago in the help-vampire wars and I disagreed with the general attitude then and I still do now. All I can see here is a person who didn't get help and got shoved out the door as fast possible. Everyone else just seems to see the rubbish getting tossed out.

Comment: Pretending they didn't exist isn't the same as completely removing the question in under an hour. Would you even bother to come back to this site if that happened to you? Especially since, and I can't believe I have to keep saying this, the question had an answer. Which leads me to believe it isn't actually as bad as everyone thinks. It just took some work to figure out what was being asked. Which means it very well could have been improved. It just would have taken you more than 5 seconds to figure that out.

Comment: 5 seconds is long enough to decide you don't want to answer it. Or even give it a down-vote. It doesn't seem like enough time to me to decide to erase the question from the site. Maybe making that decision should take a little more effort. I'm sure you disagree since you seem to think your effort should be absolutely minimized at the cost to anyone else.

Comment: @MikeD. The user was given feedback on what was problematic, was given plenty of time to address the problem, choose to do nothing with a question *so bad* that a number of people felt it didn't have any reasonable shot at being improved, and so it was deleted.  The author can use this learning opportunity to work on learning how to ask an appropriate question and not making these same mistakes going forward.

Comment: We clearly disagree on the definition of "plenty of time". People get busy. The author can't use this to learn anything. All they can see is their question is gone. They might even notice it got asked and answered again (if they're lucky) and someone else got all the points for it. That would be discouraging, eh? But who cares, they're new. I can't actually see any of the post except the screenshot because I don't have 10k rep so expecting me to know any of that is a bit much. But again, we clearly disagree on "plenty of time". I guess harsh is the way we are.

Comment: @MikeD. But the question wasn't deleted after 5 seconds.  It was deleted after an hour.   You think it takes more than hour to determine if a question is salvageable? That you think that everyone else on the site should be spending a whole lot of their time trying to moderate a question that the author appears to have spent no more than a few seconds on doesn't really make sense.  Why is their time so much more valuable than all of the time of the other people, and why is that question so much more worthy of having time spent on it than the other questions?

Comment: I didn't say any of that. I said the question could have been given a chance to live awhile longer because under an hour seems unreasonable. There is no rule that you have to delete every bad question you see so there's no reason you have to keep track of it. (I notice nobody could answer why it had be YOU rather than anyone else. I guess it is just a power trip then.) But just throw out the trash if that's what is important. I'd rather people get a chance to figure things out. I utterly fail to see how an hour is long enough at all.

Comment: @MikeD. They can see everything about their question, not just that it was deleted.  They can see what it was, what the comments on it were that indicated how it was problematic, they can see the close reason, etc.  If they do a simple search and find their answer then *that's great*.  That's not a problem at all.  They found the answer to their question, and they most likely found it way more quickly and easily than had they tried to ask a question to get that information.  Why would such an outcome be discouraging?

Comment: Anyone if a question gets enough downvotes and all that isn't it automatically deleted at some point anyway? So clearly terrible questions will be gone at some point? (I may be wrong about this. I'm unclear about the inner workings of SO automation.)

Comment: Because the accepted answer to this question is that the OP should ask this other person's question again and then answer it. Which would look like "stealing" the question to a new user. (Possibly anyway. I could see it.)

Comment: @MikeD. You're right, there is no rule that you have to delete every bad question.  The rule is that you should vote to delete questions that you think aren't salvageable.  And I *did* answer you on why has to be "you".  Because it has to be *someone*.  If everyone just says it should be someone else, then it never gets done.  At some point people that think a question is unsalvageable need to actually indicate as much, otherwise you're effectively saying the system shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: But fine I honestly give up and I'm tired of this. You can have the last word Sergey. Go for it. Less than an hour for a question that had an answer is unreasonable and shows that something went wrong. I disagree with all of this entirely and I really do not understand why it is **SO** important to get rid of people's questions as fast as possible. And I don't think I ever will.

Comment: No, just because it needs to be someone doesn't mean it needs to be YOU within the first hour the question is asked. But whatever, I give up. Have fun deleting people's questions.

Comment: @MikeD. The advice was that someone could ask a *much improved version of the question* that was actually useful and appropriate for the site.  Not that someone could just re-post the same bad question.  The existing question is *so bad* that any re-worked question would be clearly so radically different from the original that I couldn't imagine someone thinking it was "stealing", especially given that, again, the answer would in fact be useful to them, so they'd be glad to see that much improved version of the question out there (one can only hope).

Comment: @MikeD. You're quite right that something went wrong.  Someone asked a question that was *so bad* it left the community with no real recourse other than to just delete it; it was just *that* bad.  Of course that's not a desirable situation.  Ideally the question author would have taken more than a few seconds to craft an actual question and the whole situation would have been avoided.

Comment: Yeah, it was so bad that someone was about to answer it and edit it. Dodged a bullet there.

Comment: And who cares that we wasted the OP's time in writing the answer only to have the question deleted out from under him. That's happened to me too. On legitimate questions for niche technologies that took an intimate understanding of in order to tell what was being asked. But losing that content is worth it as long as people like you click on less inferior questions.

Comment: This just feels like the FGITW problem but with close and delete votes instead of answers. People want to be the person to get the bad question. It's not helpful, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, those questions did appear to be poor quality, and they were never the best. But they were always salvageable. Written by inexperienced users who may not even be sure what they're asking. But someone who knows about it can help them find the answer. Some of them I have been able to answer and improve the question. But this usually happened days or even weeks after the question was asked. If they had been nuked in under an hour it would've been lost. But go on and tell me more about how much damage these questions do by just existing.

Comment: @MikeD. The OP here had *lots* of time to edit the question.  They choose not to.  There was over 35 minutes between when they posted their answer and the question was deleted, and the question had no edits to it.  Like this user here, if you think that a bad question can be salvaged into a good one then *actually take the time to improve the question*, and only try to answer the question *after* it has been turned into a good question, it results in far better and more useful answers in addition to preventing it from being deleted while writing an answer.

Comment: @MikeD. If you really want to spend time improving quesitons, then there will still be *lots* of questions out there for you to improve, even if some of the worst of them get deleted.  SO has no shortage of questions that could use improvement.  If the current system forces you to spend more of that time on on questions that are bad, but not *so* bad, then I don't consider that a loss at all.  You're going to be much more likely to successfully salvage such a question.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. You're dismissing my experience of having real questions deleted out from under me. Which is the same thing that happened here. All in order to defend deleting questions in under an hour. I'm saying I know that good content gets missed because people are in such a rush to close and delete. I'm also saying it is probably discouraging to new users and doesn't really teach them how to write a better question. I'd rather give people a chance and help them. You think it's more important to throw out the trash as quickly as possible. We are not going to agree.

Comment: The author blew their chance when they posted a link to a screenshot with 2 errors and an isolated block of code. It was given a chance, though; 6 distinct users saw it to close it and delete it. All of them reviewed it and came to the correct decision according to site rules and guidance. This one *blatantly* violates several requirements and community expectations. It was open for over 40 minutes and wasn't deleted for over 15 more. Comments requesting improvements were left less than 5 minutes after the post was made.

Comment: Garbage is garbage. The site's too big and busy now. There are literally _millions_ of questions the OP could have used as guidance for how to form a proper question. There are posts and posts about how to do it. There is a Help Centre. They shouldn't need "teaching". There is literally **zero** excuse for a post like this. Could it have been salvaged? Probably. But do we have time to optimise for junk like this? No. Well, I don't. Clearly eclectist thinks he/she does but then they should have edited the post first. Otherwise, just delete it; it's almost entirely a lost cause.

Comment: The key point is that your chance doesn't start when the post is submitted. The chance starts when composing it begun.

Comment: _"You think it's more important to throw out the trash as quickly as possible. We are not going to agree."_ Then you misunderstand the very purpose of this website. This is a website for the many, _not_ the few (or the one).

Comment: How is that for the many? Do you assume that most people don't need help when they first start? Or that those people are somehow undeserving of being here? It seems like it's a website for people to power trip on. But I always thought of it as a help site. *shrug* I still really do not understand why it is so important that the question got deleted so quickly. Everyone seems to come at me like I'm saying this question should have stayed indefinitely but that is just twisting my words so that you can justify your elitist attitude. I just thought it should've been given more than an hour.

Comment: Thanks everyone for reminding me why I hate meta so much and why I'm not welcome in your community.

Comment: FWIW I'd advise against deleting this answer, while it's a viewpoint that's frequently downvoted on meta, in my opinion it's a rather common complaint that many people have and is worth discussing. Remember that downvotes on meta can mean disagreement, and don't necessarily mean that the post is low quality.

Comment: @Servy "if you think that a bad question can be salvaged into a good one then actually take the time to improve the question, and only try to answer the question after it has been turned into a good question," I'll mention something again that I commented on in the question -- the OP in this case has low rep, and that would have been a **suggested edit**, from my experience there's no way it would have gotten approved in an hour, wouldn't have just gotten deleted anyway? Plus wouldn't this edit be seen as turd polishing, which is discouraged?

Comment: @jrh It's pretty common for suggested edits to be applied in less than an hour, and of course anyone voting to delete a post would *see* that there are pending edits, and would be able to see whether or not said edit actually turned the post into a post worth keeping.  The author of the question could also apply the edit immediately, if they felt it improved their question.  The edit would be "turd polishing" if the question was still a bad question not worth keeping *after* the edit.  If the edit actually successfully turned the question into a good question, then no, that's not a bad edit.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, good to know, I wasn't aware that people voting to delete can see that there are pending edits. I disagree that edits are applied within an hour, from my experience even clear cut (obviously not deviating from the OP's intent) edits can take days. An edit like what you are suggesting would have a strong chance of being robo-rejected as "deviates too far from intent". Not saying it's not worth doing, but it's dangerous. I'd recommend sprinkling "100 dollar" edits like this between a majority of "5 cent" edits like fixing spelling errors, etc.

Comment: Also another thing that can occasionally help with major suggested edits is getting support from high rep users in chat; there was one edit in particular where I just happened to know the magic command line parameters that an otherwise worthless post was talking about, and it turned out okay in the long run. Definitely a plan B, I'd save that for extreme cases. Hans-esque domain expert clairvoyance is occasionally still rewarded on SO, so I don't think things are necessarily as grim as this comment thread makes it seem.

Comment: And I'd like to point out that a mod answered this question and disagreed with everything here. They pointed out that it would be auto-deleted which is something I brought up and was ignored in favor of defending this combative attitude towards new posters. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365472/201021

Comment: Off-topic questions that fall as far short of the expectations as this one should definitely be closed quickly to avoid it attracting answers, which will both be low quality/guesses and also send a signal that low quality answers will be rewarded. However, I also think the question shouldn't have been deleted so quickly. As has been said (and linked), such negatively scored and closed questions are 1) hidden from the front page, and 2) automatically deleted in about a week, and 3) don't allow people to post new answers, while 4) still allowing OP to edit/improve the post.

Comment: *They pointed out that it would be auto-deleted...* Only if it didn't have multiple answers or one up voted answer. The question in this case got one answer before it was deleted and we don't know whether it would have gotten any up votes before the Roomba got to it.

Comment: We don't know how closures & deletions count in the ban algorithm versus down votes but I do know that closing an unfixable question can stop a deluge of down votes. Typo questions are a good example of where this is important because new(-ish) users will post an answer which prevents the OP from deleting it. The answer usually gets an up vote too, which protects it from the Roomba. Meanwhile, the question is racking up down votes.

Comment: *"It's a help site"* - no. It's a *"question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"*. OP did not even post a question nor did he care to improve his post, nor did he spent time reading the how-to-ask section. I would argue 40+ minutes was far too long for the post to stay alive. ~5 minutes till closure would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Are the questions and answers not supposed to help people? I'm not seeing a difference except that you've qualified the subject matter. This question had an answer. It could have helped someone. It could have been edited and improved. But it is more important to maintain the "purity" of the site by purging anything you deem unworthy as quickly as possible. Don't give anyone a chance. Because no one gets unexpectedly busy or even if they do we shouldn't care anyway.

Comment: We don't have a system in place to delay votes on a condition. If you come across a post that is low quality, downvote it. If later on you come across it and it is no longer low quality, reverse the vote. it's simple. In this case, no improvement occurred and the question was closed. working as intended.

Comment: I never said anything about delaying votes. I am honestly fucking sick of having my words twisted and people insisting I'm saying things I'm not. No one has to keep track of every bad question. There doesn't need to be a conditional delay system on anything. Are you honestly saying a post that isn't deleted in under an hour will stay there indefinitely? Whatever. This is all simply justification for this sick attitude of superiority that makes me dislike SO.

Comment: @MikeD. It’s useful for discussions like this to keep in mind that the goal of Stack Overflow is to build a library of high-quality Q&A content.  Questions exist to help the dozens, hundreds or thousands of future Googlers with the same problem; *helping the asker is a side effect*.  That goal is the foundation of every one of the site’s rules and guidelines, and it’s the point of view from which the other comments on your answer originate.

Comment: With that in mind, another point to consider is the sheer size of Stack Overflow.  We get thousands of questions, and the ratio of answerer time to questions is low.  Once a question is no longer on the first or second page of its tag, it’s most likely received almost all the attention it ever will, which is why it’s so important for askers to make sure their questions are of the highest quality before they ask them.

Comment: The above points explain *why* the question we’re discussing was treated the way it was.  Questions are downvoted and closed to signal to the system and to other users that the question is unlikely to be useful in the current form.  On SO, there are many users and [groups of users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) who work hard to close, downvote, and delete low-quality questions as fast as possible so that high-quality questions can receive the attention they deserve.

Comment: Yes, I know there are tons of people around here that are laser focused on removing content and excluding people from the site. I don't like it. The scale of SO should mean that a question can be given a chance for more than a couple of hours AND you don't have to keep track of it. Because the large community will still come to the same conclusions later. But I've said all of this already. Your attitude of "the asker doesn't matter" is something I don't agree with. I don't see how you plan on acquiring more questions when you are so quick to dismiss questions.

Comment: To anyone else who feels like commenting on this please read what I said before. Don't twist my words. And if you don't have anything new to add beyond the overwhelming air of superiority that everyone carries around here I'm not interested in hearing it. I disagree with what most people feel is the ultimate goal of SO. I don't see anywhere in the official help documentation that tells me not to care about people asking questions and that the only benefit is to create some kind of uber-pure "documentation site"... which, as I said before, they have tried and it didn't work.

Comment: People ask questions to get help. The answers help them. The same questions and answers can go on to help more people. Great! But I fail to understand how this leads to the conclusion that questions need to be removed as fast as possible and not given a chance.

Comment: This whole attitude leaves me with the feeling that I don't want to interact with this website and its community. I imagine it drives away a lot of new people too. (I'm sure you feel they're unworthy anyway.) And as far as I can tell the general attitude is "Yeah, that's a good thing." and I don't see how making people feel excluded can be a laudable goal.

Comment: @MikeD. Why do you think actively trying to attract people who are harming the community, and who very explicitly don't *want* to take actions that the community considers beneficial, would be a laudable goal?  Not every site is designed to appeal to *everyone*.  SO is a site with a very specific mission.  Why do you think it's preferable for it to prioritize appealing to people who disagree with its mission over accomplishing said mission?  Also keep in mind that lots of SO's competitors have done as you suggest and focused on a wider appeal at the cost of quality.

Comment: The goal is not to “exclude people from the site;” everyone is included *as long as they follow the rules*.  I didn’t say we don’t care about the askers, because we do care, and we’ll help them *as long as they follow the rules*. These rules are very clear that questions must be useful to future visitors, and they’re are the reason Stack Overflow is a successful and useful site instead of degenerating into Yahoo Answers. “[That city’s littering laws are too strict. I’d leave, but for some reason every other city is covered in garbage](https://mobile.twitter.com/drob/status/618120713522802688)”

Comment: There are way more askers than there are answers and moderators.  Once a question is no longer on the front page, it has probably received all the attention it ever will, especially if it’s of poor quality.  What kind of “chance” do you think low-quality questions need to be given?  That someone will come along and edit the post into shape?  While it’s awesome when that happens, in practice it is *extremely* rare, especially if the question is as unsalvagable as the one here.  We don’t want to leave a pile of a thousand questions sitting around, hoping for to someone fix one of them.

Comment: I don't think deleting questions in minutes is why SO is a more reliable source of information than Yahoo! answers. I think that ignores a lot of how the structure of the site itself promotes good content over time. Even the evolution of mediocre content into good content and good content into great content. I would like a citation on **extremely rare** because I've improved a number of posts and I'm not very active. What kind of "chance" do I think they should be given? (Again) More time than this one got. But everyone is more interested in being superior than admit something went wrong here

Comment: I'm not sure whether this will count as "anything new to add". In any case: (1) The time, energy and attention of those who improve questions and write answers *are finite resources*. (2) [Altruism doesn't imply trying to help in every way you can think of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365148/2751851). (3) The "ultimate goal of SO" is not something made up by a bunch of zealots in Meta. [Here is an old, eloquent manifesto dedicated to it *written by a co-founder*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: Nope, none of that is new or helpful to this situation. I still say closing this question in under an hour was unreasonable. Regardless of if you are optimizing for pearls or sand. I get that the general attitude here is "we don't care about people who ask question only people who answer them." But the prevailing attitude here can drive away people who would give good answers and questions. (Like me.) But then no one cares about that either. Which is why it just feels like elitism. This question had an answer and could have been improved and the amount of time it was given was unreasonable.

Comment: I personally see the SO community as arrogant and exclusionary. I also don't think that those are good qualities. It isn't a community I want to associate with. Does the community think that is a problem? The general impression I get is "No." You have high rep users referring to new users as "mulloscoid life forms" (rude), praising deleting answerable questions as quickly as possible (impatient), and assuming  that all new users who ask a bad question are just lazy time-wasters (assuming bad faith). Should we get rid of the "be nice" rule  then? Who does it apply to?

Comment: @MikeD. [1/3] I do care about people who ask, and I do my best to have that reflected in my SO contributions. I also believe that *people should take responsibility for what they post*. In this case, the question author could have, among other things, have acted upon (or at least acknowledged) the polite, helpful comments pointing out issues with the question within three minutes of it being posted. It was his call not to do anything of the sort, and so he holds a fair share of responsibility over the consequences.

Comment: @MikeD. [2/3] Furthermore, who, other than the author, should improve that question? Fixing it is drudge work (transcribing a screenshot) that could be done much more easily, and with better awareness of context, by the author. (Also, doing that would suggest it is okay to post questions in that way and leave the drudge work to someone else.) To their credit, the OP of this Meta question has recognised that, if, in spite of the issues I just mentioned, they were so intent in answering it, they should at least *have taken responsibility* and shaped the question into something acceptable.

Comment: @MikeD. [3/3] That isn't "assuming bad faith": the question author was careless, regardless of his intentions. As for impatience: I don't *like* quick deletions, but, in flagrant cases, I understand why they happen. As noted here, not taking moderation actions risks a diffusion of responsibility scenario. In my own moderation, I try to be a little more patient, but note that I mostly watch the feed of a mid-traffic tag, a few visits a day being enough to see all questions and remember most people involved. Unlike myself, folks in larger tags and the queues have big city problems to deal with.

Comment: What about t he person who wrote this question that planned on editing it? Are they not allowed to do that? Otherwise I'm really confused why you're asking who, other than the OP, should edit the question. You're just twisting the situation around again so you can blame the new poster and ignore the entirety of this question. That doesn't seem much like you care about the question.

Comment: OMG, "careless" ... well that can't be allowed to stand. Obviously the person who posted the question was awful and just intended on wasting everyone's time. That's what you're saying right? And you're just another one of these people that is gonna say you have to make a list of bad questions because you have to be the one to close any bad question you see? A diffusion of responsibility is the entire point of community moderation. It isn't up to just you.

Comment: And I really don't follow your logic that a popular tag with lots of people needs to have  their questions deleted faster because there are less people that are going to deal with it. Do you see where that falls apart in the middle? Lots of people active in tag. Less people to deal with problem questions? Huh? *Big city problems* really? That's asinine. It's a website.

Comment: And what is the deal with this attitude of "We don't care about helping people. Making good Q&A is all that matters." while at the same time using the fact the person asking the question didn't engage with the comments **fast enough** and also blithely ignoring the fact that someone else was going to improve the question. Which is it? Do you want to punish the question writer or do you want to have good content? Because someone was going  to improve it and everyone that comes at me has little problem with how fast this question was deleted.

Comment: @MikeD. [1/5] "What about t he person who wrote this question that planned on editing it? Are they not allowed to do that?" -- I had addressed that in my "[2/3]" comment just above. They can do that, and they should have done that before answering, so that readers and reviewers wouldn't have to speculate about what they intended to do. This point was also raised in the comments to this Meta question.

Comment: @MikeD. [2/5] "OMG, "careless" ... well that can't be allowed to stand. Obviously the person who posted the question was awful and just intended on wasting everyone's time. That's what you're saying right?" -- I haven't said that at all; please don't put words on my mouth. Ignoring guidance (from other users, as well as from the site itself) was objectively a careless act. Yes, it is likely they meant to do no harm. That, however, doesn't make them any less responsible for what they have posted.

Comment: @MikeD. [3/5] By "diffusion of responsibility", I meant everyone expecting someone else to act, leading to nothing getting done. I had intended to [add a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_of_responsibility), but I ran against the character limit (and I also thought what was meant would be clear in context). In hindsight, "bystander effect" might have been a clearer choice of words.

Comment: @MikeD. [4/5] "Big city problems really? That's asinine. It's a website" -- Yes, and this is a metaphor. Big cities have issues that are qualitatively different from small town issues. The parallel lies in that moderating high-traffic tags is harder because not everything scales linearly. Notably, (1) the new questions feed -- which doesn't scale -- fills up faster, and (2) it's not just that there are more questions, but also that answers and votes accumulate faster, often making swifter action necessary.

Comment: @MikeD. [5/5] "Which is it? Do you want to punish the question writer or do you want to have good content?" -- I want good content, and also sustainable moderation across the site, because good moderation fosters good content. For all of your concern about individual instances of questions and interactions between users, you seem to disregard every and each point anyone makes about handling things at scale. "Because someone was going to improve it" -- There was no *visible* sign of that, which is why the question should have been edited before being answered. But I already have said that.

Comment: You missed the point. I got that it was a metaphor and I understand abstract concepts. What I was saying was your metaphor doesn't apply here. I've already rejected the argument of "scale" being the reason to delete this question so quickly even with people trying to help. Which is what everyone who replies to me seems to be missing. You spout off about "scale" and "carelessness" but none of that means that a question which can be answered/improved should be **deleted in under an hour**. Clearly we disagree on that point. Going around and around in circles isn't helping anything.

Comment: "You missed the point" -- I don't think so. "I've already rejected the argument of 'scale'" -- Your argument to reject it seems to boil down to "this is a website with lots of people in it, so stuff will get done eventually", an idea which you restate over and over every time anyone suggests things aren't necessarily so simple (or you cast moral aspersions on those who disagree, but let's not get into that). I don't consider that a convincing rejection.

Comment: (On a tangential note: "I got that it was a metaphor and I understand abstract concepts." -- If you don't want distracting replies to your snide comments, don't make snide comments to begin with. For someone concerned with the "be nice" and "assume good faith" principles, you have been running dangerously close to outright hostility at various places in this comment thread.)

Comment: How exactly is that hostile? You're the one who seemed to be labouring under the assumption that I don't understand what a metaphor is. Either that or your explanation had nothing to do with what we're talking about. "There are lots of people here" is a convincing rebuttal to "It has to be deleted quickly or no one will deal with it." At least to me anyway. Which is why I keep saying it when people keep repeating that argument at me.

Comment: And if I seem hostile then it is possibly related to the fact that I keep having to repeat myself when other people decide to jump in and misrepresent what I'm saying, yet again. No one has anything new to say. Nothing I've said has been a personal attack. I have expressed my feeling of the community in general and why I have always felt like it wasn't a community I wanted to be a part of. But again, I am a bit frustrated by this point. (Awhile ago if we're being accurate.)

Comment: People have been arguing with me for DAYS because they feel like questions should be deleted in under an hour. But they keep phrasing it as "the site will fall apart and be deluged by garbage if we allow every bad question!" which isn't even what I'm saying.

Comment: "How exactly is that hostile?" -- "you must be willfully misinterpreting me", "the overwhelming air of superiority that everyone carries around here", "Obviously the person who posted the question was awful [...] That's what you're saying right?", "That's asinine". Dangerously close, as I said. I'll admit "Yes, and this is a metaphor" was an unnecessary reaction to having my metaphor called "asinine" and being condescendingly told that "this is a website", so sorry for that. In any case, the immediately following remarks were entirely relevant towards better supporting the point I was making.

Comment: I don't think I'm misrepresenting you, and I don't really see that in the rest of the thread either. What people are saying here is not "*in general*, it is necessary to delete questions as quickly as possible so that the site doesn't fall apart", but something more modest: "*given the circumstances of this specific case*, the actions by the delete voters were not unreasonable". You also disagree with that, and that's okay; however, you seem to be taking ordinary disagreement as misinterpretation (or even "[williful] misinterpretation").

Comment: We must have very different definitions of "hostile". I didn't call you a "mulloscoid lifeform" which is apparently OK. (That was in an answer from a high-rep user on a related question.) So ad hominem insults are OK but expressing my views of the overall atmosphere that I feel from the community is not? It feels like you're just trying to shut me down because you can't actually respond to me about this being an unreasonable amount of time for a question that was answerable and could have been improved.

Comment: I thought your metaphor was "extremely foolish or stupid" because it doesn't make sense. (I used "asinine" because it seemed more polite but I am frustrated from repeating myself.) A website is not a city and I fail to see how it applies. It's just trying to make it sound like popular tags need a harsher response when it seems to me that the exact opposite is the case.

Comment: I'm sick and tired of the hyperbole of people talking about the "torture" of bad questions and how "if 90% of the site were these questions then everyone would leave." and "We aren't here to help people" and on and on and on and it's all really the same argument when you boil it down.

Comment: I'm also unwilling to leave the last few comments on my answer being that kind of thing which isn't at all a response to this situation or what I'm saying. I don't expect the community to change. I don't expect it will ever feel like a place I want to engage with. I was asked NOT to delete this answer because possibly others may agree since the overall negative attitude around here does come up from time to time. But I'm **really** close to deleting it just so I won't have to keep repeating myself over and over again. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Also, please understand this isn't the only place I'm having this argument. So if you'd like a wider view of my opinions go have a read through the comments on a few of the answers here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365467/what-is-a-reasonable-length-of-time-to-give-for-a-poor-question-to-be-improved-b/365472

Comment: [next to last] "But I'm **really** close to deleting it just so I won't have to keep repeating myself over and over again. Is that what you're after?" -- Not at all: I believe unpopular opinions on Meta should not be deleted, precisely for the reason you mention. I will stop posting in this comment thread. Before that, though, there is one final tangential point in your latest batch of comments I can't help but reply to, so I'll ask of you one more sliver of patience. My apologies.

Comment: [really the last one here] "I didn't call you a 'mulloscoid lifeform' which is apparently OK." -- No, it is absolutely not OK, and I never suggested otherwise. Again, don't put words in my mouth. Also, please try not to treat me as if I were part of some hive mind of high-rep-rude-elitist-exclusionary users.

Comment: No, but in responding to you I am also trying to respond to the community in general. A high-rep user called new users that and just had a mod edit their post and then another high-rep user edited back in a bunch of the bad faith assumptions that the mod removed. I take this as tacit approval of those actions as long as they're done by the right people. So I'm not trying to treat you as part of some hive-mind but your opinions align well with the problem that I have with the general community's attitude. **But it doesn't matter anyway. I'm out. Have fun...**