# Is chat abbreviation allowed in answer?

Tags: discussion, revision-history

I used some chat abbreviations in my answers and found that someone tried to remove them like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42887142/revisions

So I want to know if it's allowed here.

I did some search with google about this question, but found nothing.

Comment: Would you write a formal letter with such abbreviations?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think downvotes are rude. You are not new to Stack Overflow, so your should know by now that the goal of the site is to build a repository of high-quality Q&As. Maybe it is too obvious to the downvoters, that this goal forbids the use of _txt spk_.

Comment: You get downvoted because peoeple disagree with: "*I used some chat abbreviations in my answers*".

Comment: But it has nothing to do with this question. I asked this question, people can read this page by searching. Isn't it helpful? @Mistalis

Comment: @honk Maybe not that obvious I thought.

Comment: Voting on meta is different but it won't cost you rep so don't bother about.

Comment: @blackmiaool [Voting culture on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta)

Comment: Why did you want to write your answers that way to begin with? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @Don'tPanic  It's widely used in questions. And it can actually save my time.

Comment: _And it can actually save my time_. It takes me the same amount of time to write _u_ as it does to write _you_. You should write questions using proper English. Show effort in your questions and it will be reciprocated.

Comment: Sure. I know that by asking this question and reading answers. @Bugs

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"Txt spk" is frowned upon, and should be edited out. We're a site for professionals (and enthusiast amateurs). "U" and other forms of "txt spk" are not professional.

So, please use proper English in your posts. And if you see someone use "txt spk" or "l33t spk", by all means convert it to proper English!

The only thing we **don't** do is changing American English to British English, or vice versa. Both are considered proper English, and merely a matter of the OP's taste.

Answer (score 7):

People don't use here text-speak chat abbreviation in posts, because SO is not a social networking platform, some people may not get the context and might downvote your Q&A.

Quote from [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

> Please write actual words. There are undoubtedly some abbreviations
>   which are acceptable to most readers – IMO, IIRC etc –  there’s no
>   reason to switch into text-speak with “gr8”, “bcoz”, “u” and so forth.
>   It’s unlikely that you’re actually writing your question on a phone
>   with only a primitive keyboard; show your readers respect by writing
>   properly. It may take you a few more seconds, but if it means you get
>   an answer quicker, it’s surely worth the extra effort.

and from [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! Remember, this is the
>   first part of your question others will see - you want to make a good
>   impression. If you're not comfortable writing in English, ask a friend
>   to proof-read it for you.