# How does this system support questions about symptoms that have multiple root causes?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, duplicate-answers

It's a theme in service management frameworks, such as [ITIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL). A symptom can have multiple root causes. There are cases of unique root causes, that do not get coverage, because they duplicate a question with the same symptom. The questions are marked as duplicate or closed.

I've found cases where moderation regarding questions that beget "answer collections". These questions seem to attract text heavy treatments that can take forever to plow through.

A benefit of answer collections might be that they could prevent accidental false flagging of issues that look like duplicates but that are not.

- Java null pointer exceptions (NPEs) where the API indicates that a method could not return a null value. Or, an open source project where the project code is throwing an NPE and it's likely somebody else has had the time to dig into the open source code.  This is a common issue using open source projects such as [Apache Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons).
- A 'not initialized error' which occurs inside a complex synchronization block and thus it's not 'obvious' as it's the synchronization code that is causing the initialization error.

I assume we've been through this before, but I can't find anything on this subject in the discussions, and nothing in the canonical questions.

Comment: *and then to be closed when it's perceived that the number of answers is getting out of hand*: Citation needed. The number of answers doesn't play a role regarding closure. There might be a lock if too many duplicate answers are posted by newcomers.

Comment: Let me ask you this: when you ask your new "unique" question after "read[ing] through a lot of different [existing] answers", do you *explicitly mention* the other Q&As that you've read? Do you make it obvious to all readers that you've already referenced the existing questions, and explain why you've found them to be lacking in regards to your unique problem? If not, then it's your fault that your questions get closed as duplicates: you didn't provide any reason *not* to close them as duplicates. If you are doing this, then perhaps there was some overzealousness.

Comment: How does this manage to make it down -25? I don't see 25 upvotes on comments.  I thought 'meta' was for open discussion.  Does  a downvote mean an issue is unworthy of discussion?  Annoying?

Comment: @Cody Gray Here is an example of a question I posted on an NPE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848439/how-use-the-apache-tika-1-16-sourcecodeparser

Comment: All right now someone has marked this as a duplicate -- but with no comment or explanation.  What exactly is the "canonical rule" that is being referenced?  thanks.

Comment: @BDL Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.  The problem with this, is that via the moderation process, it sometimes shuts down questions about a library (e.g., third party or sun/java) breaking a contract.  As soon as the words "null pointer exception" appear in a post, it gets closed ,even though there might be a chance to capture someone's effort in digging through API code or what not.

Comment: @John Just for reference, [voting tends to work differently on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272607/11047824).

Answer (score 19):

The abstraction of "answer collections" seems either moot at best or confusing at worst, since every question can have a collection of answers associated with them.

This does *not* have anything to do with question moderation, though.  Far from it.  If nothing else, more than say...5 or 6 answers on a given question is a [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Questions that are duplicates should be closed.  **Full stop.**  There is no value in restating the same "this is why you have an NPE" rationale for someone *else's* code base.  One would also conjecture that if you find an NPE in a library you're using, then you should take that up with the maintainers of the library as opposed to Stack Overflow.

I'd like to respond to this explicitly:

> It is very frustrating to read through a lot of different answers, post a unique question, and then get into an argument, eventually escalated to meta or to chat, where the question is reopened, and then reclosed by a new zealous moderator.

It is equally frustrating to see the curation activity that we do to make this site appealing for one to want to post their dang question here in the first place as an "argument", and its even worse to be labeled as "zealous" when it comes to content curation.  If you desire something *more* than Q&A, go to Reddit or a forum and allow us our curation.

Comment: I apologize for my tone. It's just that I have experienced moderation actions that occurred very quickly, and after I've done a lot of ground work without comment or explanation. I will remove tone. With the NPE example I cited in the comment above, I had to go into chat and plead my case to get the question reopened.

Comment: In the example above, I had a question about Apache Tika. Tika is somebody else's code base. It's not honoring the specified API contract.  Apache Tika is on the tag list. Should I presume that a product on the tag list, is out of bounds?