# Can we have a delete option for suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

## Problem

I am currently at the limit for pending suggested edits. All my pending edits aren't being reviewed by anyone, so without a way to delete them, I can't suggest edits at all. **I want to be able to delete one, then start over on an entirely different post.**

## Feature Request

Can we have a feature for deleting your own edit suggestions? I'm not asking that there be a change in the pending cap, just a way to delete suggestions that are preventing you from making more.

Comment: I'm not clear on what benefit there would be from such a feature. You'd still be rate limited, so you could only have 5 pending suggested edits at any given point of time. Why does it matter *which* 5 edits are pending?

Comment: you can get rid of the ones that you don't want anymore

Comment: What do you mean "don't want anymore"? I sincerely hope you're only suggesting edits that you think are meaningful.

Comment: If nobody is ever going to review your edit, like if the user is no longer active, then you can delete the edit so it doesn't stay pending forever.

Comment: That's not really how it works at all. In addition to the owner of the post who can approve the edit, there are review queues where your suggested edits go, and they are reviewed by whichever users it's presented to. Don't worry about it, your edits will get reviewed eventually.

Comment: Actually, the author of the post is not the only one who can review your suggested edit. So, no, it shouldn't stay pending forever. Replacing a pending suggested edit with a new one won't solve your problem because it would be pushed to the queue and remain pending until it gets reviewed just like the one it replaced would have.

Comment: but it still is possible for it to stay pending for a long time, and clog up your pending limit.

Comment: @jeffthechicken ...which is also true for the new edit. Right? So, what do you gain from replacing a pending edit with another pending edit?

Comment: Yes, but without deletion, you can get to a point where all 5 pending edits aren't getting resolved and you cannot change them or make new edits.

Comment: Please read all the links that are shared with you. In your previous meta question, you were shown links that explained both that you can change pending edits, and the reason for the rate-limit of 5 pending edits. Which part of that are you unclear about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you completely remove an edit once you suggest it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405344/how-do-you-completely-remove-an-edit-once-you-suggest-it)

Comment: No, I don't want to change an existing edit, I want to delete it and suggest an edit on an entirely different post.

Comment: no, that was one of my own questions :)

Comment: @yivi Well, that is what I am suggesting, anyways

Comment: Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258136/how-do-i-write-a-good-feature-request) when making feature requests and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/11407695) - one of, if not the best commentaries I've seen on making one's point across when requesting something to change.

Comment: [A couple edits to 5 contributions won’t change the fact you still will be question banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405330/why-did-i-get-question-banned-for-a-question-that-didnt-get-voted-down)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are no advantages in making suggested edits "revocable".

- No advantage for the one making the suggestion: there is simply no way to know the **next** suggestion is going to have a speedier reviewing.
- No advantage to the system: If one could cancel their suggestions, other users could be wasting their time reviewing edits that one could take back before the review queue is done with them.

Simply focus on making edits you will not want to “revoke”, and accept that since other users need to review your suggestions, sometimes you will have to wait.

You have a single pending suggestion at the moment. Be patient and focus on quality over quantity.

Comment: The problem is also that a suggested edit that could be in second position in the review queue is removed and replaced from a suggested edit that goes on the bottom of the review queue. I don't think the last suggested edit is going to be reviewed quickly, except in the case the users handle the suggested edit from the question page and the question was one of the last asked questions (or bumped on the front page for some reason).